# What are the advantages of using getters and setters instead of functions or simply public fields in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, coding-style, getter

I'm not a PHP developer, so I'm wondering what the advantages and disadvantages are in PHP to using explicit getter/setters, in a pure OOP style, with private fields (the way I like):

```
class MyClass {
    private $firstField;
    private $secondField;

    public function getFirstField() {
        return $this->firstField;
    }
    public function setFirstField($x) {
        $this->firstField = $x;
    }
    public function getSecondField() {
        return $this->secondField;
    }
    public function setSecondField($x) {
        $this->secondField = $x;
    }
}
```

or just public fields:

```
class MyClass {
    public $firstField;
    public $secondField;
}
```

Comment: PHPstorm... generate > getters and setters.  == win

Comment: @DevDonkey Not a win at all. For holding structured data, use arrays instead. @:Mark This is not what objects are or are for. Getters and setters are evil: https://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You can use [php magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) `__get` and `__set`.

```
<?php
class MyClass {
  private $firstField;
  private $secondField;

  public function __get($property) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
      return $this->$property;
    }
  }

  public function __set($property, $value) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
      $this->$property = $value;
    }

    return $this;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: @BoltClock - actually it will. __get and __set are called for directly unacessible properties. As the fields are declared as private, the class will check for __get and __set whenever those properties are called.

Comment: Don't you need an extra paren after `if (property_exists($this, $property)` <-- here?

Comment: Whats the benefit against `public` properties, if there are no validation/sanitation?

Comment: @KingCrunch, this is just an example. A very very dummy example for a powerful resource.

Comment: Eh, you've got the right idea. Perhaps you abbreviated for sake of example? If you have a variable you truly want private, using a class like this entirely eliminates the benefits of encapsulation. I'd recommend creating a switch statement to handle each property on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: That's not really setter and getter. Typically I need for each property different implementation of getter!

Comment: Please don't : With magic methods you'll LOOSE almost every quality-related features, in many IDE (even vim) : auto-completion, explicit PHP inheritance, fast PHP interpretation & usefull PHPDoc generation & output. cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6184893/490589

Comment: @Ronan: you can avoid losing those features. Simply declare the properties in the class and then unset() them in the constructor. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php and search for the string "phpDocumentor".

Comment: Please refer to this post and chosen answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713680/php-get-and-set-magic-methods. __Get and __Set is not proper to use they are for error handling!

Comment: @KingCrunch, the benefit should be obvious: If you later want to add validation/sanitation, it doesn't break existing code that uses it.

Answer (score 123):

Why use getters and setters?

1. **Scalability**: It's easier refactor a getter than search all the var assignments in a project code.
2. **Debugging**: You can put breakpoints at setters and getters.
3. **Cleaner**: Magic functions are not good solution for writting less, your IDE will not suggest the code. Better use templates for fast-writting getters.

[image: direct assignment and getters/setters]

Comment: If you use @property, your IDE will suggest the code (tested with PhpStorm 7)

Answer (score 61):

Google already published a guide on optimization of PHP and the conclusion was:

**No getter and setter** [Optimizing PHP](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625191431/https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php)

And no, you must **not use magic methods**.  For PHP, Magic Methods are evil. Why?

1. They are hard to debug.
2. There is a negative performance impact.
3. They require writing more code.

PHP is not Java, C++, or C#. PHP is different and plays with different rules.

Comment: I tend to agree with that idea; that `$dog->name = 'fido'` is better than `$dog->setName('fido')`. When actually mutating a property (ex: `$dog->increaseAge(1)` I can build out the method that does the necessary validation and mutates that property. But not all actions really require mutation in that sense.

Comment: The article *doesn't* say "**don't**", it's says 'naive setters and getters'.

Comment: Google's code for php on github contradicts their article then. They use all kinds of setters/getters (naive and so on): https://github.com/google?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=php

Comment: It's safe to assume that an article written by Google that has the headline "PHP performance tips" is NOT intended to suggest good coding style, but fast code execution. The chapter that deals with setters and getters is labeled "Avoid writing naive setters and getters", and the code example is exactly that: Naive. It sets and gets just a variable without any validation. THIS kind of setter/getter is useless. Doing validation inside a setter (simply use a type hint for the method argument) will make setters/getters useful because now your code KNOWS what it is dealing with.

Comment: this is like saying that inline styling is better. of course the performance is better, but is it better code? I didn't know google engineers use php anyway

Comment: Several things missing with this.  While its true that you shouldn't be naive (make everything setters/getters), thats also true of the other languages as well. $obj->var = $value; makes sense, but it SHOULD be translated into $obj-setVar($value) when executed.  Not only that, but people seem to make the assumption that all properties should be read/writable and that they don't affect ANYTHING else.  For example, i prefer  $obj->name, but if i want it to be readonly i have to make it a function $obj->getName();. $name = $obj->name should work but $obj->name = $var should fail.

Answer (score 19):

Encapsulation is important in any OO language, popularity has nothing to do with it. In dynamically typed languages, like PHP, it is especially useful because there is little ways to ensure a property is of a specific type without using setters.

In PHP, this works:

```
class Foo {
   public $bar; // should be an integer
}
$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar = "string";
```

In Java, it doesn't:

```
class Foo {
   public int bar;
}
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
myFoo.bar = "string"; // error
```

Using magic methods (`__get` and `__set`) also works, but only when accessing a property that has lower visibility than the current scope can access. It can easily give you headaches when trying to debug, if it is not used properly.

Comment: Getters and setter doesn't bring encapsulation. Encapsulation == objects do something with its own data instead of giving them outside. Getters and setters are not a tool for enforcing type in dynamically typed languages like PHP.

Comment: @smentek: You're clearly missing at least half of what encapsulation really is.

Comment: As an update to this for anyone looking, PHP 7.4 will come with typed property support. So you could declare `$bar` as an `int` in the first example: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2

Answer (score 7):

If you preffer to use the __call function, you can use this method. It works with

- GET => `$this->property()`
- SET => `$this->property($value)`
- GET => `$this->getProperty()`
- SET => `$this->setProperty($value)`

kalsdas

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) {

    //Getting and setting with $this->property($optional);

    if (property_exists(get_class($this), $name)) {


        //Always set the value if a parameter is passed
        if (count($arguments) == 1) {
            /* set */
            $this->$name = $arguments[0];
        } else if (count($arguments) > 1) {
            throw new \Exception("Setter for $name only accepts one parameter.");
        }

        //Always return the value (Even on the set)
        return $this->$name;
    }

    //If it doesn't chech if its a normal old type setter ot getter
    //Getting and setting with $this->getProperty($optional);
    //Getting and setting with $this->setProperty($optional);
    $prefix = substr($name, 0, 3);
    $property = strtolower($name[3]) . substr($name, 4);
    switch ($prefix) {
        case 'get':
            return $this->$property;
            break;
        case 'set':
            //Always set the value if a parameter is passed
            if (count($arguments) != 1) {
                throw new \Exception("Setter for $name requires exactly one parameter.");
            }
            $this->$property = $arguments[0];
            //Always return the value (Even on the set)
            return $this->$name;
        default:
            throw new \Exception("Property $name doesn't exist.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @krzysztof-przygoda: This "Magic Methods" always come with a price. They have to use recursion `property_exists(get_class($this), $name)` and recursion is slow. There is a way y to mitigate this with cacheing, but it's still going to be slower than creating the getters and setters by hand. I only wrote this as an alternative. I actually don't recommend using "Magic Methods". The extra time of creating the getters and setters is usually insignificant.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the already great and respected answers in here, I would like to expand on PHP having no setters/getters.

***PHP does not have getter and setter syntax***. It provides subclassed or *magic* methods to allow "hooking" and overriding the property lookup process, as pointed out by *Dave*.

**Magic** allows [us lazy programmers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/does-so-encourage-developer-laziness) to do more with less code at a time at which we are actively engaged in a project and know it intimately, but usually at the expense of readability.

**Performance** Every unnecessary function, that results from forcing a getter/setter-like code-architecture in PHP, involves its own memory stack-frame upon invocation and is wasting CPU cycles.

**Readability:** The codebase incurs bloating code-lines, which impacts code-navigation as more LOC mean more scrolling,.

**Preference:** Personally, as my rule of thumb, I take the failure of static code analysis 
as a sign to avoid going down the magical road as long as obvious long-term benefits elude me at that time.

**Fallacies:**

A common argument is readability. For instance that `$someobject->width` is easier to read than `$someobject->width()`. However unlike a planet's `circumference` or `width`, which can be assumed to be  `static`, an object's instance such as `$someobject`, which requires a width function, likely takes a measurement of the object's instance width.
Therefore readability increases mainly because of assertive naming-schemes and not by hiding the function away that outputs a given property-value.

**__get / __set uses:**

- pre-validation and pre-sanitation of property values
- strings e.g.

  ```
  "
  some {mathsobj1->generatelatex} multi
  line text {mathsobj1->latexoutput}
  with lots of variables for {mathsobj1->generatelatex}
   some reason
  "
  ```

  In this case `generatelatex` would adhere to a naming scheme of actionname + methodname
- special, obvious cases

  ```
  $dnastringobj->homeobox($one_rememberable_parameter)->gattaca->findrelated()
  $dnastringobj->homeobox($one_rememberable_parameter)->gttccaatttga->findrelated()
  ```

*Note:* PHP chose not to implement getter/setter syntax. I am not claiming that getters/setter are generally bad.

Answer (score 6):

```
class MyClass {
    private $firstField;
    private $secondField;
    private $thirdField;

    public function __get( $name ) {
        if( method_exists( $this , $method = ( 'get' . ucfirst( $name  ) ) ) )
            return $this->$method();
        else
            throw new Exception( 'Can\'t get property ' . $name );
    }

    public function __set( $name , $value ) {
        if( method_exists( $this , $method = ( 'set' . ucfirst( $name  ) ) ) )
            return $this->$method( $value );
        else
            throw new Exception( 'Can\'t set property ' . $name );
    }

    public function __isset( $name )
    {
        return method_exists( $this , 'get' . ucfirst( $name  ) ) 
            || method_exists( $this , 'set' . ucfirst( $name  ) );
    }

    public function getFirstField() {
        return $this->firstField;
    }

    protected function setFirstField($x) {
        $this->firstField = $x;
    }

    private function getSecondField() {
        return $this->secondField;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();

echo $obj->firstField; // works
$obj->firstField = 'value'; // works

echo $obj->getFirstField(); // works
$obj->setFirstField( 'value' ); // not works, method is protected

echo $obj->secondField; // works
echo $obj->getSecondField(); // not works, method is private

$obj->secondField = 'value'; // not works, setter not exists

echo $obj->thirdField; // not works, property not exists

isset( $obj->firstField ); // returns true
isset( $obj->secondField ); // returns true
isset( $obj->thirdField ); // returns false
```

Ready!

Comment: Too much boilerplate. Imagine this stuff being in every class. Avoid IMO

Comment: PHP does not support getters and setters for the same reasons you mention. Any implementation of this type affect the performance of server-side script severely.

Comment: I think this goes against 'private' properties. You encapsulate them, but also allow to access directly.

Comment: @KorayKüpe only if the getter is defined. I use this encapsulation a lot (with many improvements) and it works perfectly. You can also extend the class and use it in all the code easily.

Answer (score 6):

I made an experiment using the magic method __call.
Not sure if I should post it (because of all the "DO NOT USE MAGIC METHODS" warnings in the other answers and comments) but i'll leave it here.. just in case someone find it useful.

---

```
public function __call($_name, $_arguments){
    $action  = substr($_name, 0, 4);
    $varName = substr($_name, 4);

    if (isset($this->{$varName})){
        if ($action === "get_") return $this->{$varName};
        if ($action === "set_") $this->{$varName} = $_arguments[0];
    }
}
```

Just add that method above in your class, now you can type:

```
class MyClass{
    private foo = "bar";
    private bom = "bim";
    // ...
    // public function __call(){ ... }
    // ...
}
$C = new MyClass();

// as getter
$C->get_foo(); // return "bar"
$C->get_bom(); // return "bim"

// as setter
$C->set_foo("abc"); // set "abc" as new value of foo
$C->set_bom("zam"); // set "zam" as new value of bom
```

---

---

This way you can get/set everything in your class if it exist so, if you need it for only a few specific elements, you could use a "whitelist" as filter.

Example:

```
private $callWhiteList = array(
    "foo" => "foo",
    "fee" => "fee",
    // ...
);

public function __call($_name, $_arguments){
    $action  = substr($_name, 0, 4);
    $varName = $this->callWhiteList[substr($_name, 4)];

    if (!is_null($varName) && isset($this->{$varName})){
        if ($action === "get_") return $this->{$varName};
        if ($action === "set_") $this->{$varName} = $_arguments[0];
    }
}
```

Now you can only get/set "foo" and "fee".
You can also use that "whitelist" to assign custom names to access to your vars.
For example,

```
private $callWhiteList = array(
    "myfoo" => "foo",
    "zim" => "bom",
    // ...
);
```

With that list you can now type:

```
class MyClass{
    private foo = "bar";
    private bom = "bim";
    // ...
    // private $callWhiteList = array( ... )
    // public function __call(){ ... }
    // ...
}
$C = new MyClass();

// as getter
$C->get_myfoo(); // return "bar"
$C->get_zim(); // return "bim"

// as setter
$C->set_myfoo("abc"); // set "abc" as new value of foo
$C->set_zim("zam"); // set "zam" as new value of bom
```

---

.
.
.
That's all.

---

**Doc:**
[__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.

Comment: The problem with all these "magic" solutions is that they simply use these magic methods because they are there, and they are useful because the problem asked is a simple, generic one. Once you leave this level of generic problem, you will encounter specific requirements that cannot be solved by a simple magic method, but would require a very complex magic method - or individual, coded setters and getters.

Answer (score 5):

Well, *PHP* does have magic methods `__get`, `__set`, `__isset` & `__unset`, which is always a start. Alas proper (get it?) OO properties is more than magic methods. The main problem with PHP's implementation is that magic methods are called for *all* inaccessible properties. Which means you have to Repeat Yourself (eg. by calling property_exists()) in the magic methods when determining if *name* is actually a property of your object. And you can't really solve this general problem with a base class unless all your classes inherit from ie. ClassWithProperties, since PHP lacks multiple inheritance.

In contrast, *Python* new style classes gives you `property()`, which lets you explicitly define all your properties. *C#* has special syntax.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)

Comment: Calling property_exists, class_vars or array_key_exists (ie, checking if property really exists) is just a step in order to avoid a runtime fatal error. I'm not sure if not being displicent is the same as being repetitive in coding.

Comment: Fair enough. But in Python and C# this repetition is not needed. I think that is a strength.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the other advices, I'm inclined to say that:

As a **GENERIC** rule, you will not always define setters for **ALL** properties, specially "internal" ones (semaphores, internal flags...). *Read-only* properties will not have setters, obviously, so some properties will only have getters; that's where __get() comes to shrink the code:

- define a __get() (magical global getters) for all those properties which are alike,
- group them in arrays so:

  - they'll share common characteristics: monetary values will/may come up properly formatted, dates in an specific layout (ISO, US, Intl.), etc.
  - the code itself can verify that only existing & allowed properties are being read using this magical method.
  - whenever you need to create a new similar property, just declare it and add its name to the proper array and it's done. That's way *FASTER* than defining a new getter, perhaps with some lines of code REPEATED again and again all over the class code.

Yes! we could write a private method to do that, also, but then again, we'll have MANY methods declared (++memory) that end up calling another, always the same, method. Why just not write a **SINGLE** method to *rule them all*...? [yep! pun absolutely intended! :)]

Magic setters can also respond ONLY to specific properties, so all date type properties can be screened against invalid values in one method alone. If date type properties were listed in an array, their setters can be defined easily. Just an example, of course. there are way too many situations.

About *readability*... Well... That's another debate: I don't like to be bound to the uses of an IDE (in fact, I don't use them, they tend to tell me (and *force* me) how to write... and I have my likes about coding "beauty"). I tend to be consistent about naming, so using ctags and a couple of other aids is sufficient to me... Anyway: once all this magic setters and  getters are done, I write the other setters that are too specific or "special" to be generalized in a __set() method. And that covers all I need about getting and setting properties. Of course: there's not always a common ground, or there are such a few properties that is not worth the trouble of coding a magical method, and then there's still the old good traditional setter/getter pair.

Programming languages are just that: human artificial languages. So, each of them has its own intonation or accent, syntax and flavor, so I won't pretend to write a Ruby or Python code using the same "accent" than Java or C#, nor I would write a JavaScript or PHP to resemble Perl or SQL... Use them the way they're meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the first way is more popular overall because those with prior programming knowledge can easily transition to PHP and get work done in an object-oriented fashion. The first way is more universal. My advice would be to stick with what is tried and true across many languages. Then, when and if you use another language, you'll be ready to get something accomplished (*instead of spending time reinventing the wheel*).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create sourcecode in a netbeans-convention. This is nice. It makes thinks such easyer === FALSE. Just use the traditionel, specially if you are not sure which one of the properties should be encapsuled and which one not. I know, it is a boi.... pla... code, but for debugging-works and many other thinks it is the better, clear way. Dont spend to much time with thousend of arts how to make simple getters and setters. You cannot implement too some design patterns like the demeter-rule and so on, if you use magics. In specific situation you can use magic_calls or for small, fast and clear solutions. Sure you could make solutions for design-patters in this way too, but why to make you live more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

### Validating + Formatting/Deriving Values

Setters let you to validate data and getters let you format or derive data. Objects allow you to encapsulate data and its validation and formatting code into a neat package that encourages DRY.

For example, consider the following simple class that contains a birth date.

```
class BirthDate {

    private $birth_date;

    public function getBirthDate($format='Y-m-d') {
        //format $birth_date ...
        //$birth_date = ...
        return $birth_date;
    }

    public function setBirthDate($birth_date) {                   
        //if($birth_date is not valid) throw an exception ...          
        $this->birth_date = $birth_date;
    }

    public function getAge() {
        //calculate age ...
        return $age;
    }

    public function getDaysUntilBirthday() {
        //calculate days until birth days
        return $days;
    }
}
```

You'll want to validate that the value being set is

- A valid date
- Not in the future

And you don't want to do this validation all over your application (or over multiple applications for that matter). Instead, it's easier to make the member variable protected or private (in order to make the setter the only access point) and to validate in the setter because then you'll know that the object contains a valid birth date no matter which part of the application the object came from and if you want to add more validation then you can add it in a single place.

You might want to add multiple formatters that operate on the same member variable i.e. `getAge()` and `getDaysUntilBirthday()` and you might want to enforce a configurable format in `getBirthDate()` depending on locale. Therefore I prefer consistently accessing values via getters as opposed to mixing `$date->getAge()` with `$date->birth_date`.

getters and setters are also useful when you extend objects. For example, suppose your application needed to allow 150+ year birth dates in some places but not in others. One way to solve the problem without repeating any code would be to extend the `BirthDate` object and put the additional validation in the setter.

```
class LivingBirthDate extends BirthDate {

    public function setBirthDate($birth_date) {
        //if $birth_date is greater than 150 years throw an exception
        //else pass to parent's setter
        return parent::setBirthDate($birth_date);
    }
}
```

Comment: However, many times you need to validate properties together (and not just individually). I think allowing "setters" means you also aren't capturing context. Validation should be done on a contextual basis. Also, you will be forced to check some "isValid" flag on every method you have (and perform validation if it's false). That being said, setters do provide a useful way to type-hint, such as when you have a property that you want to be a Value Object (ie. Money).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by being forced to check an "isValid" flag? If the only way to set values is through setters that perform validation, then you know the data is valid by the fact that it was successfully set. If you need to validate properties together, you can write a common validation method that the setters of those properties call.

Comment: Say you have an employee class with `setHired` and `setHireDate`. It's not valid to let someone set a hire date without also setting the employee as hired. But there is no way you enforced this. If you enforce it in one of these setters, than you are forcing the order of "setting", and that requires more code reading from a developer to know. Then when you go to do a method like `$employee->promote($newPosition);` you have to check a flag to see if validation was done or assume it hasn't been done and do it again (redundant).

Comment: Instead, capture the interactions. Perhaps `$employee->updateWorkStatus($hired, $hireDate);` or if more advanced `$employee->adminUpdate(\Employee\AdminUpdateDTO $dto);`. Now you can validate in the context you need and decide if any extra validation is needed at all.

Comment: updateWorkStatus is essentially a setter function that sets 2 instead of 1 value but the concept is the same. That's one way to do it but you can also put the contextual validation in a common method that's only run when all properties that need to validated together are set i.e. the contextual part of the validation would be called by both setHiredDate and setHired but would only run if both isset hired and isset hiredDate were true.

Comment: updateWorkStatus sets 2 things, correct, but it does it all at one time. Big difference there. You aren't letting `set and set and set` happen. In between "sets" you have invalid state. Plus you don't have any source or intention on the setting to work with. You suggest adding a validation check on all properties in each setter, but what if I only run one setter? Say I run `setHiredDate` and not the other?

Comment: All this being said, Fuzzy, allowing setters and just doing an isValid check on your methods is not wrong. I think it's more about knowing which strategies involve what. In general though, people usually have a standard validation check, and it's usually only needed on methods that accept some kind of external input perhaps. So if you gather all your "setting" situations and instead bundle together into single-context methods, then you can just put your validation call there and not worry about other methods on employee (or requiring $employee->validate() after they finish calling the setters)

Comment: I agree that you should have a single setter for values whose validation depends on each other if its not legal to set one value without setting the other. But I still don't see how that would require an isValid flag or how its an argument against using setters for validation :)

Comment: No worries. But don't just take my word for it. Do some researching on the web of how setters can be bad and don't reveal intention. And anemic domain models. Setters are good for things like DTOs though.

Answer (score 0):

This post is not specifically about `__get` and `__set` but rather `__call` which is the same idea except for method calling. As a rule, I stay away from any type of magic methods that allow for overloading for reasons outlined in the comments and posts *HOWEVER*, I recently ran into a 3rd-party API that I use which uses a SERVICE and a SUB-SERVICE, example:

```
http://3rdparty.api.com?service=APIService.doActionOne&apikey=12341234
```

The important part of this is that this API has everything the same except the sub-action, in this case `doActionOne`. The idea is that the developer (myself and others using this class) could call the sub-service by name as opposed to something like:

```
$myClass->doAction(array('service'=>'doActionOne','args'=>$args));
```

I could do instead:

```
 $myClass->doActionOne($args);
```

To hardcode this would just be a lot of duplication (this example *very* loosely resembles the code):

```
public function doActionOne($array)
    {
        $this->args     =   $array;
        $name           =   __FUNCTION__;
        $this->response =   $this->executeCoreCall("APIService.{$name}");
    }

public function doActionTwo($array)
    {
        $this->args     =   $array;
        $name           =   __FUNCTION__;
        $this->response =   $this->executeCoreCall("APIService.{$name}");
    }

public function doActionThree($array)
    {
        $this->args     =   $array;
        $name           =   __FUNCTION__;
        $this->response =   $this->executeCoreCall("APIService.{$name}");
    }

protected function executeCoreCall($service)
    {
        $cURL = new \cURL();
        return $cURL->('http://3rdparty.api.com?service='.$service.'&apikey='.$this->api.'&'.http_build_query($this->args))
                    ->getResponse();
    }
```

But with the magic method of `__call()` I am able to access all services with dynamic methods:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $this->args     =   $arguments;
        $this->response =   $this->executeCoreCall("APIService.{$name}");   
        return $this;
    }
```

The benefit of this dynamic calling for the return of data is that if the vendor adds another sub-service, I do not have to add another method into the class or create an extended class, etc. I am not sure if this is useful to anyone, but I figured I would show an example where `__set`, `__get`, `__call`, etc. may be an option for consideration since the primary function is the return of data.

---

EDIT:

Coincidentally, I saw this a few days after posting which outlines exactly my scenario. It is not the API I was referring to but the application of the methods is identical:

[Am I using api correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881224/am-i-using-api-correctly)

Answer (score -2):

Update: Don't use this answer since this is very dumb code that I found while I learn. Just use plain getter and setter, it's much better.

---

I usually using that variable name as function name, and add optional parameter to that function so when that optional parameter is filled by caller, then set it to the property and return $this object (chaining) and then when that optional parameter not specified by caller, i just return the property to the caller.

My example:

```
class Model
{
     private $propOne;
     private $propTwo;

     public function propOne($propVal = '')
     {
          if ($propVal === '') {
              return $this->propOne;
          } else {
              $this->propOne = $propVal;
              return $this;
          }
     }

     public function propTwo($propVal = '')
     {
          if ($propVal === '') {
              return $this->propTwo;
          } else {
              $this->propTwo = $propVal;
              return $this;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Now the question remains: How do you set a property to the empty string? And how do you detect that setting a property to the empty string actually failed and worked as a getter? Just think about HTML forms sending empty fields as strings... And no: Using a different value such as NULL as the default value does not solve the problem.