# Having trouble getting __set to set and __get to get in PHP

Tags: php, oop, get, set

According to this answer here: [Getter and Setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478661/getter-and-setter)
The following function should work, however it produces no output.

```
<?php
class UserInfo{
  private $username;
  private $privileges;

  public function __get($property) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
      return $this->$property;
    }
  }

  public function __set($property, $value) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
      $this->$property = $value;
    }

    return $this;
  }
}

$user=new UserInfo;
$user->__set($username,"someuser");
echo $user->__get($username);
?>
```

http://codepad.org/jwMaeVMN

Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you would have to use `"username"` instead of the undefined `$username` when passing the property name to the function.

However, this is not how magic getters and setters work in the first place. You're supposed to set using `$user->username = "someuser";` that will automatically trigger  the setter:

```
$user=new UserInfo;
$user->username = "someuser";
echo $user->username;
```

Comment: Wow thanks. I read the manual I swear, I just couldn't tell how the methods were being invoked. This must be why they call them magic.

Answer (score 1):

To set:

```
$user->username = "user";
```

To get:

```
$username = $user->username;
```

Answer (score 1):

When this line is called:

```
$user->__set($username,"someuser");
```

there is no $username in scope, and you're passing a null parameter into the method call.

The call should be

```
$user->__set('username', 'someuser');
```