# How to call getter and setter from within a javascript class

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call getter and setter from within own class ? If yes what's the valid syntax instead of invalid

```
this.gettext();
```

in below class :

```
  class Test {

    _text: string;
    constructor(value: string) {
      this._text = value;
    }

    get text() {
      return this._text;
    }

    set text(value) {
      this._text = value;
    }

    test () {
      return this.gettext();
    }
  }
```

Comment: `return this.text`. Getters and setters are used like normal properties (not functions)

Comment: As a side-note, JS classes now support true private fields using the hash symbol `#text: string`, rather than having to rely on underscore hints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use getters and setters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151298/how-to-use-getters-and-setters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setters are called during asignment and getters during reading.

```js
this.text = "testing..."
```

will call the setter passing "testing..." as a value.

```js
console.log(this.text)
```

will call the getter

If you need to treat as a callable method, wrap it inside a method or don't use properties (getters/setters), use a method instead. If,  as you show, you want to wrap it in another method for some reason:

```js
test() {
   return this.text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
test () {
   return this.text;
}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, although it would greatly benefit from an explanation.