# Make a variable behave like a function

Tags: php

I'm making a PHP script which works with polynomials and monomials (an example of monomial is `42xk^2c^3d`). The `Monomial` class is defined as follows:

```
class Monomial {
    public $coefficient; // i.e. 42
    public $letters;     // an array of Letter objects
    public $literal;     // i.e. xk^2c^3d
    /* Code */
}
```

Now, in my applications I use both the array of letters and the literal variable. I don't want to update "by hand" the `literal` variable whenever I update the monomial (e.g. when adding something to it): instead, I want it to be dynamical, so that accessing it calls a function to "build" it. Any ideas?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4478690/801544)

Comment: Yes, the magic methods in php `__get` and `__set` should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function `setLetters` (or even `updateMonomial`) which updates both your variables and use that instead of accessing the variable directly. It's generally a good idea to not expose class members.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__get` method. An example:

```
class Monomial {
    public $coefficient;
    public $letters;
    public $literal;

    function __get($var) {
        if ($var != "literal") {
            return $this->data[$var];
        } else {
            foreach ($this->letters as $letter) {
                $return.=$letter->literal;
            }
            return $return;
        }
}
```

There would be a similar `__get` method in the `Letter` object which would generate the literal string on request.