# Why is $this not the correct type of object?

Tags: php, oop, medoo

I'm trying to implement a simple PHP db framework (Medoo) into PHPLib, but am stuck on the following:

I have this structure

index.php which initiates

- new medoo object
- new application object

the application class handles general settings for each app, and extends from my medoo class.

Each app has its own class (e.g. Foo) , and an foo/app.php file. the foo class extends from the application class.
the foo/app.php file generates the view, and in this file a foo object is created.

But it's in the Foo class i'm trying to connect with my database with the medoo class.
The medoo class has some protected properties which are accessible within the Foo class
(e.g. $this->medoo_property)

but whenever i'm trying to run use a method from the medoo class i'm getting stuck at this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function something() on a non-object in something

when I do a var_dump of $this right before the error in the medoo class, it says it is an Foo object instead of a Medoo object. So it's obvious it throws an error of non-object, because it tries to use a medoo property in a Foo object.

I have the same error implementing another php (PDO) class, so the error is on my side, but I can't figure out what it is I'm doing wrong.
I hope my problem is explained properly, feel free to ask more info if needed.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a bit off code to your question? the Classes and the Index?

Comment: @KhorneHoly

application.php
http://pastebin.com/grBGFDKq

actual example of Foo class
http://pastebin.com/UqRqTfP6

actual example of foo/app.php
http://pastebin.com/VdDxxvu8

index.php
http://pastebin.com/eNmD0Akh

Comment: If "application" is a "medoo", then it probably doesn't make sense for it to contain a "medoo" -- but you are constructing a "medoo" inside your "application". There's possibly something fundamentally broken about your object model here I think?

Answer (score 0):

I think, from your code and description given, that your facing a scoping problem.

If your calling `$this` in the `Foo` class, you're not going back to the `Medoo` (Parent) Class, `$this` refers in this case to the direct instance of `Foo`. So you're calling a function that's not given. As you said already.

What you need is the [Parent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) function from PHP, so you can call the functions from `Medoo` in `Foo`.

As simple example taken from the official documentation:

```
<?php
class A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am A::example() and provide basic functionality.<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am B::example() and provide additional functionality.<br />\n";
        parent::example();
    }
}

$b = new B;

// This will call B::example(), which will in turn call A::example().
$b->example();
?>
```

Also you should not set all properties to `public`, it's bad practice and bad scoping. You should set them to `private` if no child of this class should be able to easily access them or `protected` if childs should access and manipulate them.

To further gurantee the accessabilty to this properties you need [getter and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478661/getter-and-setter).

Comment: I have Foo extends from application, which extends from medoo, I can't use parent::parent::get  ?
I know the public is bad practice, but I'm a little desperate in solving this problem that I tried a whole buch of things :p

and using a single parent still shows that $this right before the error still is a Foo object.. I had expected Application?

Comment: I even tried parent::get in the foo class combined with
parent::__construct() in the application class

Answer (score -1):

fixed it by replacing this with self in the medoo class, and making the properties static