# Php error string conversion

Tags: php, class

I have this code. And i need to print those strings. But i can't make changes outside the class. So i need to change inside class to work. The fields must remain private. Any ideas?

```
class STUDENT {
    private $nume,$prenume;
    # Constructor 
    public function __construct($nume , $prenume){ 
        $this->nume=$nume;
        $this->prenume=$prenume;            
    } 

}

$student = new STUDENT("one","two");  
echo "student: ". $student ."<hr/>";
```

Comment: You have to implement `__toString` method: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: thanks. it solved it. now you need to respond properly so i can add reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define [`__toString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method. Then you can `echo` instance as `string`:

```
class STUDENT {
    private $nume,$prenume;

    public function __construct($nume , $prenume){ 
        $this->nume=$nume;
        $this->prenume=$prenume;            
    } 

    public function __toString()
    {
        return '{nume:'.$this->nume.','.prenume:'.$this->prenume.'}';
    }
}

$student = new STUDENT("one","two");  
echo "student: ". $student ."<hr/>";
```

Comment: public function __toString(){
  return $this->nume." ".$this->prenume;
 }        this is wrong?

Comment: hmm. aparently student name needs to be red. can you help with that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use getters and setters so the fields can be read and written. Here's a discussion on the subject: [Getter and Setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478661/getter-and-setter)

Comment: thank you. i used at other problems. i have some examples.. and i need to learn setter and getter and magic __set or __get.