# Connection to mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql

```
class DatabaseConnection{
  private $connection;
  private $username;
  private $password;
  private $serverName;
  private $database;
  private $database_found = false;

  //constructor with params
  public function __construct($database,$username,$password,$serverName){
    $this->$username = $username;
    $this->$password = $password;
    $this->$serverName = $serverName;
    $this->$database = $database;
  }

  //estabilish database connection
  public function connect()
  {
    $connection = mysql_connect($this->serverName,$this->username,$this->password);
    if($connection)
    {
      echo "Connection was successful!\n";
      $db = mysql_select_db($this->database,$connection);
      if($db)
      {
        echo "Database found!\n";
        $this->database_found = true;
      }
      else{
        echo "Database not found!\n";
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "Failed to connect to the database!\n";
    }
  }

  //closes connection
  public function close_connection(){
    mysql_close();
    echo "Connection closed!\n";
  }

  public function getConnection(){
    return $this->connection;
  }

  public function getDatabaseState(){
    return $this->database_found;
  }
}
```

This is my class for database connection. It connects to mysql, but for some reason it doesn't want to connect to the database (I've tried to insert database name as a string in `mysql_select_database` but still does not work). Database exist cause It was manually created. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you should rather use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). [Here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is the first tutorial I found.

You also use `$this->$username` where you should use `$this->username`. Here is [the official tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) about PHP classes.

Also, the convention is to write private variables in classes with an underscore at the start, like this:

- `private $_username;` to create it ;
- `$this->_username` to call it.

You can also create getters and setters to interact with your variables. ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8955492/4255615))

Comment: I know the practics of OOP :) just used Java but for this project is better for me PHP

Answer (score 2):

You currently have:

```
$this->$username = $username;
```

this should be:

```
$this->username = $username;
```

You have 4 occurrences of this.

Comment: I had it like you say than I get warning
Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in E:\xampp\htdocs\catchrecorder\database.php on line 22

Answer (score 0):

Check your access rights at MySQL.
 Is the user allowed to use the given DB?

Comment: Yes It is , I've developing just on local machine database was created by me , and I'm using the root account