# is class variable store data for access anywhere in php?

Tags: php, class

i would like to know. is php class variable store data for access anywhere in class without performing again.

suppose that

```
class myclass 
{
  public $date;

    public function __construct(){
     $this->date = date('Ymd');
    }
}

$myclass = new myclass();

$myclass->date;
```

so as above code if i am using `$myclass->date;` three time in my code. it means `date()` function runs three time ? or just run one time and store current date in class variable and not utilize CPU power three time in same task?

Comment: Using `$myclass->date` you're referencing a property value, not calling a function, so as long as you're not instantiating a new myclass instance whenever you need it, the actual date function is only being called once in the constructor

Comment: The constructor is only run when you create a new object, not when you access a property of an existing object.

Comment: Yes so it means i can access property value without calling a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function __construct(){
 $this->date = date('Ymd');
}
```

Will run just once, when you reference the class i.e. on:

```
$myclass = new myclass();
```

if you want to check for date each time when you call, you have to make a function:

```
public function currentDate(){
    return date('Ymd');
}
```

and then call it like:

```
$currentDate = $myclass->currentDate();
```

Answer (score 1):

as jeroen said the constructor is called only at initialisation.
You can change the value of date anytime outside the class by:

`$myclass->date = date('Ymd');`

You may see example here: http://codepad.org/oPZlwnOS
If you wish more adequate handling use getters and setters with private method state. See  [here more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478661/getter-and-setter)