# How to display data outside of the class which is from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, pdo

I'm confused how to display data from class.

I have database with entries and I created a sql request inside of a class:

```
class Posts 
{

public function getPosts (  ) {

    $returnValue = FALSE;


    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_modified";

    try {
        $pdoCore = Core::getInstance();
        $pdoObject = $pdoCore->dbh->prepare($query);

        if ( $pdoObject->execute() ) {

            $pdoObject->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


            while ( $posts_row = $pdoObject->fetch() ) {

                $this->posts[] = $posts_row;
            }

            $returnValue = TRUE;
        }           
    }
    catch ( PDOException $pe ) {
        trigger_error( ' Veritabanindan bilgiler alinamadi. ' . $pe->getMessage() );
    }

    return $returnValue;

} 
}
```

and I'm trying to display it with this code

```
$posts = new Posts();

$posts->getPosts();


foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

as you notice I get `Notice: Array to string conversion` error and if I declare $this->posts as an array the page is blank.

Can you explain me how should retrieve data in this situation. is this approach right?

thanks.

Comment: `foreach ($posts->posts as $key => $value)` ?

Comment: yes all the data from database `array(12) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2015-01-04 00:00:00" ["post_content"]=> string(18) "Ilk Yazininin yazi" ["post_title"]=> string(8) "ilk yazi" ["post_status"]=> string(6) "active" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "active" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["post_type"]=> string(4) "text" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["TotalVotes"]=> string(1) "0" ["VoteSum"]=> string(1) "0" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foreach, `$posts` is the instance object of the `Posts` class, so it doesn't make sense to try to iterate the Posts object. Instead, I would build an array in the `getPosts` method and return it, rather than creating the `posts` property and returning a boolean.

Below, `$returnValue` is the local array that gets returned.

```
public function getPosts (  ) {

    $returnValue = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_modified";

    try {
        $pdoCore = Core::getInstance();
        $pdoObject = $pdoCore->dbh->prepare($query);

        if ( $pdoObject->execute() ) {

            $pdoObject->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


            while ( $posts_row = $pdoObject->fetch() ) {

                $returnValue[] = $posts_row;
            }

        }           
    }
    catch ( PDOException $pe ) {
        trigger_error( ' Veritabanindan bilgiler alinamadi. ' . $pe->getMessage() );
    }

    return $returnValue;

}
```

Then the usage:

```
foreach ($posts->getPosts() as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['post_title'];
}
```

Comment: hi thanks. instead of `$returnValue[] = $posts_row;` and `return $returnValue;` i used `$this->posts[] = $posts;` and `return $this->posts;` and it works now. Can you explain me what is the difference between $this-> and $retrunValue which one should I use. For example would I need $this-> in future. I'm just trying to learn OOP in php

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem**

I'm assuming that you have a `posts` field in your class that you didn't post here (because you do access it as `$this->posts`).

What happens in your `foreach` loop is that it iterates over all the fields of the `Posts` class, and echoes them (which doesn't make all that much sense, but ok). The problem is that `posts` is not a string, but an array, and you can't echo arrays. If you use `print_r` it should display you something.

**Fixing the problem**

What you actually want to do is return the posts in `getPosts`, and then iterate over that. So basically, return `$this->posts` (or an empty array for no posts, an exception for error), and then do something like this:

```
$posts = new Posts();

$posts2 = $posts->getPosts();

foreach ($posts2 as $key => $value) { // iterate over posts
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) { // iterate over values of that post
    echo $value2;
}
```

**A possibly better solution**

Note that the variable names here are pretty bad. This is mainly because your posts object is unconventional. I would expect a `Post` object which contains fields such as `name`, `last_modified`, etc. A `Posts` class with a field containing a list of posts doesn't really make all that much sense (it's just a list of `Post`s, no need for a class).

If you want to add methods to retrieve all posts, you don't really need to store the resulting list in a class, just return the list of `Post` object, then you can iterate over that.

So I would change your code to:

```
class Post {
    $name;
    $last_modified;

    // constructor

    // getters
}

class PostDAO {

    public function getAll() {
        // retrieve posts from db, return array of Post objects
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
$postDAO = new PostDAO();
$posts = $postDAO->getAll();

foreach ($posts as $post) { // iterate over posts    
    echo $post->getName();
    echo $post->getLastModified();
}
```

The advantage is that this decouples how posts are retrieved from the database from the rest of your code (eg displaying your posts).

Comment: how can I achieve this? $post->getName(); can you give me an example for getAll() method please?

Comment: @ErdemEce see here for how [getters work in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478661/getter-and-setter) (it's pretty much the same as in most language, eg Java, etc; I would not use magic methods, because they can't be documented and there is no auto-complete). `getAll` would just be what you already have, but without returning true/false (which isn't all that useful; if there is an error, just throw an exception), and returning an array of objects instead (created via something like  `$returnValue[] = new Post($posts_row['column_name1'], $posts_row['column_name2'], [and so on];`).

Answer (score 0):

Your method getPosts() assign values to property $posts of object $posts. Try it:

```
$posts = new Posts();

$posts->getPosts();

foreach ($posts->posts as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: I get these errors Notice: Undefined property: Posts::$posts in /var/www/tutorial.dev/index.php on line 16

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/tutorial.dev/index.php on line 16

Comment: Because you must declare this property in your class