# Setting request values in constructor in php

Tags: php, oop

I have a simple form field with 3 input fields. I am trying to use the oop concept to write the code. 
Is it good practice to get the request values in constructor, so that I can use these values in every method.

```
function __construct()
{
  $this->country = mosgetparam( $_REQUEST, 'country','');
  $this->month = mosgetparam( $_REQUEST, 'month','');
  $this->year = mosgetparam( $_REQUEST, 'year','');

}
```

This is just an older version of joomla. So no need to bother about the syntax.

Note: more info: I am submitting the form with country, month and year. I need these values to generate some reports. So is it okay to set the values in constructor so that I can get these values inside the methods?

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Also it will be helpful if you can explain a bit about getting and setting the request values using a method and using those in some other methods.

Comment: Never ever hide your arguments. I.e. you should pass `array $data` to ctor and class  itself should not know from where it's coming.

Comment: so you suggest to set the request values outside the class and then pass it to the methods?

Comment: Yes, I do suggest that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyClass {

    protected $country;
    protected $month;
    protected $year;

    public function __construct($aParams)
    {
        foreach ($aParams as $sParam => $mValue) {
            if(property_exists(get_class($this), $sParam)){
                //ANY validation, including filter_var
                $this->$sParam = $mValue;
            }
        }
    }
}

$oMyClass = new MyClass(['month' => 'qqqqqq', 'year' => 34234]);
//OR
$oMyClass = new MyClass($_GET);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
class MyClass {
   function __construct($country, $month, $year) {
       $this->country = $country;
       $this->month = $month;
       $this->year = $year; 
   }
}

var obj = new MyClass(mosgetparam( $_REQUEST, 'country',''),mosgetparam( $_REQUEST, 'month',''),mosgetparam( $_REQUEST, 'year',''));
```

you can do it this way.
hope it helps :)

Comment: So if I have say more than 10 parameters to pass, this method is okay? Also is this completely depending on oop? Any suggestion to set and get values through class itself?

Comment: this function follows oop concepts. this link will be helpful for getters and setters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478661/getter-and-setter