# How do I get a JSON representation of a class which uses getters and setters?

Tags: php, json, object, entity, getter-setter

I am new to getters and settings, and want to start trying them.  I see how I can retrieve a single property, but how can I receive retrieve properties or all of them in JSON format such as `{"firstField":321, "secondField":123}`.  I've tried `public function get(){ return $this;}` and even `public function getJson(){return json_encode($this);}` but just get empty JSON.

PS.  Is `return $this;` in the setter a typo or does it provide some value?

```
<?php
class MyClass {
  private $firstField;
  private $secondField;

  public function __get($property) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
      return $this->$property;
    }
  }

  public function __set($property, $value) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
      $this->$property = $value;
    }

    return $this;
  }
}
?>
```

Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/4478690/1032531

Comment: Implement JsonSerializable interface

Comment: `return $this` it isn't typo, it's make method chainable.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs  Thanks for the chainable comment.  Still looking into http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php.  Seems like a lot of work, and am hoping that getters and setters are actually a good thing.  I know some don't like magic methods, but the issues are the same even if I don't use them.

Comment: Why do you think implementation of JsonSerializable is look like a lot of work? You need implement only one method which just returns assoc array like this `['prop1'=>$this->prop1, 'prop2'=>$this->prop2]`

Comment: @NobbyNobbs  I don't think it is a lot of work (anymore).  It works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Highly inspired by NobbyNobbs.

```
abstract class Entity implements \JsonSerializable
{
    public function __get($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) return $this->$property;
        else throw new \Exception("Property '$property' does not exist");
    }

    public function __set($property, $value) {
        if (!property_exists($this, $property)) throw new \Exception("Property '$property' is not allowed");
        $this->$property = $value;
        return $this;
    }
}

class Something extends Entity
{
    protected $name, $id, $data=[];

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'data' => $this->data
        ];
    }
}
```