# php output constructor array

Tags: php, arrays

I tried executing the code below to output each value from an array, end up result show:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\tutor.php on line 22
_data : Array
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
class CateData 
{
    private $_data = array();

    public function __construct($data){

        $this->_data = $data;
    }
}

$data = array(
            'a'=>'Cate1',
            'b'=>'Cate2',
            'c'=>'Cate3',
            'd'=>'Cate4'
        );

$cate = new CateData($data);

foreach($cate as $key => $val){
    echo $key." : ". $val;
}
?>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please read up on the basics of [OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looping on the class object and not on the actual data.

In your class add:

```
public function getData(){
   return $this->_data;
}
```

**Then change:**

```
foreach($cate as $key => $val){
    echo $key." : ". $val;
}
```

**To:**

```
foreach($cate->getData() as $key => $val){
    echo $key." : ". $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should clear the differences between `public` `protect` and `private`.

In your code, you should change your `_data` to public because you want to visit outside your class.

Then change:

```
foreach($cate as $key => $val){
    echo $key." : ". $val;
}
```

to:

```
foreach($cate->_data as $key => $val){
    echo $key." : ". $val;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and why *should* they change the visibility of the property? A [getter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8955492/2263631) would be better as suggested by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is better, an alternative is to change the scope so you you dont need to add a getData() method. But can then access the class variables directly.

//change the variable to public, and loop `$cate->_data`

```
class CateData 
{
    public $_data = array();

    public function __construct($data){

        $this->_data = $data;
    }
}

$data = array(
            'a'=>'Cate1',
            'b'=>'Cate2',
            'c'=>'Cate3',
            'd'=>'Cate4'
        );

$cate = new CateData($data);


foreach($cate->_data as $key => $val){
    echo $key." : ". $val;
}
```

Comment: No, it would be better practice you use a [getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478661/getter-and-setter/8955492#8955492) function as suggested by the accepted answer. No need to mess with the visibility.