# How can I get data from object with foreach loop in Symfony?

Tags: arrays, symfony, oop, foreach, formbuilder

```
$EntityName = 'App\\Entity\\' . ucwords($slug);
$item = new $EntityName();    
$item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($EntityName)->find($id);
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
```

content of `$item`:

```
object(App\Entity\Members)#4788 (6) {
  ["id":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  int(9)
  ["username":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  string(13) "123"
  ["plainPassword":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  NULL
  ["password":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["email":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  string(7) "1@12.sw"
  ["isActive":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

I try to get the fields from $item.

As an output I want to have

```
id
username
password
email
isActive
```

to create the fields.

My approach is:

```
foreach($item as $field){
   echo $field;
}
```

But I do not get any output

Comment: Usually that's done by using getters

Comment: @revengeance The problem is that I need to get just every field that is in the object, with getters I only know to get a specific field if you already know the name of the field, but what if you do not know what is inside the object and want to get a kind of list of all fields inside

Comment: Got you. I would write proper answer, but I'm from phone now. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php There is answer. Basically you can cast to array or use get object vars function (from inside the class to get private variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot loop over the properties of an object like that. If you want to do this in a loop you would have to provide an array of the properties.

```
foreach(['id', 'username', 'email'] as $field){
   echo $item->{$field}
}
```

If you just wanted to print one property you would do it like this:
`$item->username`

Comment: My bad since the properties are private it will not be available to `get_object_vars`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I cannot do it like this, because this information `'id', 'username', 'email'` is actually what I need as an output

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of object properties with [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), and from each of these you can get to the value of each property using the magic method __get(). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4478690/546262). EDIT: You actually don't even need the magic method... the `get_object_vars` returns values already.

Example modified from the above links:

```
class Foo {
    private $a;
    private $d;

    public function getAllFields() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

Then you can get all (non-static) properties, including private properties, with this:

```
$item = new Foo();
$fields = $item->getAllFields();
```

and you can get values of each field like so:

```
foreach ($fields as $fieldName => $fieldValue) {
    echo $fieldName . ' has value ' . $fieldValue;
}
```

This is untested code, but should work.

Comment: Sure it can, just place `get_object_vars` within the class code, literally straight from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php). I'll update my answer to show.