# how can i set value to an array like chaning methods?

Tags: php, arrays, set, arrows

i wanna set value with key to an arrau like chaning

I just want to know how Laravel did it

this is laravel code of eloquent update query

```
$variable=Model::find(3);
$variable->columnname="name";
$variable->save();
```

this is my code

```
$variable=["name"=>"Eric","email"=>"example@gmail.com"]; 
$variable->name="jack";
$variable->email="testest@gmail.com";
print_r($variable); or $query="update tblname ..."
```

It doesn't work and it give me error

how this system work

Comment: Really no idea what your asking.  There is no chaining and the two snippets don't have any correlation.

Comment: `->` is used with objects, not arrays. You need to define a class.

Comment: i jus want to know how this laravel system work  , find method return an array by id and i can use variable->keyarrayiscolumnname=setvalue How does Laravel get the values this way?

Comment: can you give me sample code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing some things up here I guess.

```
// Array syntax
$array = [];
$array['key'] = 'value'; // adding "value" to the array with the key "key"
$array['key'] = 'newValue'; // Values can be changed like this.

// Object syntax
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->key = 'value'; // adding "value to the object with as the attribute "key"
```

BUT this would just be for a standard Class. When you are using an already existing class (in your example "Model") you can not always access or change the attributes. That's why you can often see methods like

```
$obj->getName(); //to get the value of "name" of the class
$obj->setName(); // to set...
```

[Getter and Setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478661/getter-and-setter) I did a quick search. I think the link should clear up a couple of things. And for your code:

```
// option 1, create a class with getter and setter, see link
// option 2
$variable = new stdClass;
$variable->name = "Jack";
...
```