# PropertyUtils.getProperty fails when trying to get a simple property value

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I've a strange issue with the `PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, fieldName)` method, where I got a `java.lang.NoShuchMethodException`.

Suppose we have a simple java class called pojo:

```
public class Pojo {
    public java.util.Date aDate;
    public java.util.Date theDate;

    public Pojo(){}
}
```

and a caller class like

```
public class TestPojo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pojo p = new Pojo();
        p.setADate(new Date());
        p.setTheDate(new Date());

        PropertyUtils.getProperty(p, "theDate");
        PropertyUtils.getProperty(p, "aDate");
    }
}
```

The first `PropertyUtils.getProperty` call works fine, and the second one will `throw` the `NoSuchMethodExeption`.

I would like to know if I'm missing something stupid or it's really a bug :)

Comment: What is `PropertyUtils`? It is not a standard Java class.

Comment: Calling PropertyUtils.getProperty(p, "ADate"); works fine :o

Comment: it's org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils from common-beanutils

Comment: @Jesper not standard but part of Apache Commons, a de facto standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand how `PropertyUtils.getProperty(p, "TheDate");` could work since the name of the property is not correct.

Try this:

```
public class TestPojo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pojo p = new Pojo();
        p.setADate(new Date());
        p.setTheDate(new Date());

        PropertyUtils.getProperty(p, "theDate");
        PropertyUtils.getProperty(p, "aDate");
    }
}
```

Link to the [PropertyUtils method](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

To Solve your problem, two solutions:

- use property name "ADate" instead
- change your accessors method names to getaDate() and setaDate(Date dateToSet)

As Xavi said it is a [reported bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEANUTILS-369)

Comment: you're right, it was just a typo error, I edited the question :)

Comment: @Fred +1 Thanks for your credit, but it's not exactly a bug. It's [java.beans.Introspector](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html)'s behavior, following the [Java Beans Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/docs/spec.html), because of which the names used to access properties are derived out of the getter/setter methods no matter how's the property named in the bean. The standard states that the first letter will be converted to lowercase **except** if the first two letters are uppercase. In this case the name remains unchanged.

Comment: @Fred Sorry for all the fuss, but you know, when [duty calls](http://xkcd.com/386)...

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEANUTILS-369)

> The Java Bean Specification states in section "8.8 Capitalization of
>   inferred names" that when the first character is converted to
>   lowercase unless the first two characters are both uppercase then the
>   property name is "unchanged".

Adapting the rest for you (in *italics*):

> So when you have a getter method named *"getADate"* this is
>   translated into property name *"ADate"* and not *"aDate"*.
>
> So to resolve your issue you have two choices:
>
> - use property name *"ADate"* instead or
> - change you method names to *"getaDate"* and *"setaDate"*

Comment: I thought I had found a BUG inside commons-beanutils and it is the naming convention (in my case my property was called "xPos")

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
PropertyUtils.getProperty(p, "ADate");
```

instead of

```
PropertyUtils.getProperty(p, "aDate");
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you need using:

```
PropertyUtils.getProperty(p, "ADate");
```

where A in UPPERCASE

Comment: getters and setters [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/tutorial-on-getters-and-setters)