# C++ Accessing private vector values

Tags: c++, vector, private

I'm doing a restaurant management program. Right now I'm trying to output private vector data and am getting stuck.

So I have a Menu.h

```
private:
vector<Category> categories;
vector<Menu_Item> menu_items;
vector<Recipe> recipes;
vector<Ingredient> ingredients;
vector<Order> orders;
vector<Order_Item> order_items;
```

And Menu.cpp

```
Menu.read()
Menu.show()
```

The read function reads from a file like this

```
1010    Appetizers                                      
1901    Entrees                                     
1576    Desserts                                        
1320    Drinks
```

And stores those values into the appropriate vector, for example this one would be vector categories.

I also have a .h file for all the different types of things like, Menu_Item.h, Recipe.h, etc. And I store values into the vector like such:

```
menu_items.push_back(Menu_Item(meniID, catID, rID....
```

However in Menu_Item.h the values are

```
private:
int menu_item_id;
int cat_id;
int recipe_id;
string menu_item_name;
double price;
```

The show() function queries the user what he/she wants to see. Let's say the user wants to see a specific menu item like Onion rings. What I can't do is

```
if(menu_items[0].menu_item_name == "Onion Rings")
```

because it says that menu_item_name value is private within Menu_Item.h. How can I access the private data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make menu_items public or make a public getter function like the following.

```
public: 
   vector<Menu_Item> get_menu_items(){ return menu_items;}
```

Then say if you had a Menu object of this type called Menu you can do this:

```
if(Menu.get_menu_items()[0].menu_item_name == "Onion Rings")
```

The other possible option is that you make a friend class if another specific class needs access, though usually this won't be the best design decision.

In response to the comment you could do this:

```
for(size_t n=0, n<menu_items.size()-1, ++n){    
     if(Menu.get_menu_items()[n].menu_item_name == "Onion rings")
          cout << "something";
}
```

Comment: Now my idea was to do something like this                          `code for(int n=0, n<menu_items.size()-1, ++n){ if(menu_items[i].menu_item_name == "Onion rings")                 cout << "something"; }`.                                          How can I do something like that or use the above function?

Comment: it says menu_item_name is inaccessible

Comment: Make menu_item_name public. Or make a get_menu_item_name() getter function.

Comment: Sorry I'm getting very lost. I'm trying to use the for loop and I can't make any of those private variables public. So I made this `code string get_mi_name(){ return menu_item_name;}` then i have the `vector<Menu_Item> get_menu_items()`. However I have no idea how to get anything. Can you please clear this up for me.

Comment: @Richard: the `Menu_Item` class should have a `public: const string& get_name() const {return menu_item_name;}`  Then in your loop instead of using `menu_items[i].menu_item_name` you type `menu_items[i].get_name()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Declare your fields in Menu_item.h as `public`, not `private`.
2. Keep your fields as `private`, but create `public` [getters (and setters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/tutorial-on-getters-and-setters) to access the fields.