# Access Integer Value From Another Class

Tags: java, class, variables, integer

How would I go about accessing data in one java class from another one? For example, I declare an integer with a value in class_one.java and want to make use of that data in class_two.java.

Comment: I know this question is very simple, but I'm trying to learn and I often don't know where to start when I get stuck like this.

Comment: You need to go through some good Java Tutorial. [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) would be a good starting point.

Comment: I realize that I have a lot to learn. However, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes, Mr Doctor. You have to learn a lot. So, do that! Search for java tutorial for beginners. Take your time and learn. Do not ask trivial question: they can cause damage to your reputation.

Comment: I most certainly am, but in the meantime I wanted to find an answer so I can make a little more progress with what I'm working on. Do not be rude as that can cause damage to your reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either declare the variable as public:

```
public class class_one {
  public Integer myValue;
}
```

or create a public getter (preferred), such as:

```
  public class class_one {
    private Integer myValue;

    public Integer getMyValue() {
      return myValue;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Expose your variable via a [getter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/tutorial-on-getters-and-setters) and call that method on an instance of the desired class.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the first class in the other class and simply use its variables, if declared public in the first class.

```
class Foo
{
   public int a=10; 

}
```

In the other class, do this

```
Foo a=new Foo();
int test = a.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

a) `public` :visible for all classes
b) `protected` : visible in subclasses and classes in the same package
c) `default` : visible for classes in the same package

This works for variables and method access.

Answer (score 0):

One one is to build a "get" function which will return the desired value

such as

```
public int getA(){
   return a;
}
```

Another easy solution would be to use  static variables. 
Put the "static" keyword before a variable:

```
static int a=5;
```

and to access the variable you use the class:

```
Class_One.a;
```

this would use the variable as if it were inside the same class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your variable is declared. Here is the Oracle tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access a variable of one java class in other java class using either of the following ways:

> 1. Declaring the accessing variable as public and accessing it directly in other class. But You should avoid it as it leads to tight
>      coupling.
> 2. Declaring the accessing variable as private and accessing it via getter Method . It is the preferred way of accessing variables as it
>      keeps the variable safe from accidentally changing in other class.
> 3. Using `reflection` package .