# Storing data members in objects

Tags: java

How do I put/access data stored to/from a object?

I'm trying to make a very simple game so I made an object array to store information about the the players like so:

```
     player[] p = new player[4];
```

then put the player objects into the array like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
p[i] = new player();
}
```

the above should create an array with 4 elements with a player object in each.

now... is where I get lost. is this the syntax for putting data members into a object?

```
player() = {name, turn, rolledNumber}
```

// String name, boolean turn, int rolledNumber

//got this off wiki probably not a safe bet, but after searching for hours on the Oracle Tutorial site and other java tutorial sites I came up empty handed. I have seen this done with arrays so maybe I thought it would be similar in some aspects.

sorry if this is a empty headed question, I'm just beginning to learn java as a hobby.

Comment: You should follow correct Java naming conventions (capitalize class names)

Comment: Please post the code for the `player` class. Also, note that the Java naming conventions suggest that class names should start with upper case and variable names should start with lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a default constructor for `Player`, you could add one that takes the arguments for `name`, `turn` & `rolledNumber`, then you could use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  p[i] = new Player(name, turn, rolledNumber);
}
```

The individual class member variables can still be accessed via setters & getters. This is known as [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Java [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) indicate that classes take an initial capital letter, so `player` has been writen as `Player` here in accordance with the guidelines.

Comment: I see... Is there a way to retrieve an individual data member from those objects. would it be something like: `player(name);` for just the `boolean turn` or would I have to list all the parameters like in method calling, then use some manual way of extracting the individual data member?

Comment: You would use a _getter_ like `player.getName()`. Note `player` here is an _instance_.  See [Setters & Getters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/tutorial-on-getters-and-setters).

Answer (score 1):

In order to store information into state (i.e. in this case name, turn, rolledNumber) variables within the Player class, you need to either set them in a custom constructor, make them public (generally a bad idea), or provide getter/setter methods. Given that you will likely want to change the data in turn and rolledNumber later, but not name one possible solution would be to implement a class with a constructor and getter/setter methods as follows...

```
public class Player
{
    private String playerName;
    private boolean playerTurn;
    private int rolledNumber;

    public Player(String name, bool turn, int number)
    {
        playerName = name;
        playerTurn = turn;
        rolledNumber = number;
    }

    public String getName() { return playerName; }
    public boolean getPlayerTurn() { return playerTurn; }
    public void setPlayerTurn(boolean turn) { playerTurn = turn; }

    ...

}
```

Then you call the constructor as per Reimeus' example above.

Comment: You will need to create getter/setter methods for playerTurn also.