# sorting an ArrayList using private instance variables of an object

Tags: class, variables, arraylist, instance, private

I hope this question makes sense.  I have a class called Item that has private instance variables name, quantity, and price.  Then I have a class called ItemList that extends Item and puts objects of the class Item into an ArrayList.  I have no problem printing out the variables of those objects, but I'm trying to sort the objects within the ArrayList by price and I'm not sure how to access the private instance variables within the derived class in order to sort the objects.  Does this make sense?  Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Why does `ItemList` extend `Item` at all? Subclassing implies an "is-a" relationship. Is an `ItemList` a special/specific type of `Item`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to extend Item to ItemList.
Secondly if you want to access private variables of any class then you should have methods returning values of those variables.

you can have something like setters and getters.

have a look at this question may solve your problem.

[tutorial on getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/tutorial-on-getters-and-setters)

Or you can go googling for some advance informations.