# Selected element not set to the backing bean

Tags: jsf

I have following field in my jsp. Selected value is not set to the element. 
When I did Inspect element on this drop down field in FF, it shows that element is not selected. Also its not set to the backing bean.
What am I missing?

```
    <h:selectOnMenu id="scriptEngine"  value="#{AddScriptBean.scriptEngine}" required="true">
        <f:selectItems value="#{AddScriptBean.scriptEngines}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

The backing bean code is as follows

```
    public List<SelectItem> getScriptEngines() {
    List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    try { 
        GetScriptEngineNamesCommand command = (GetScriptEngineNamesCommand) CommandFactory.getInstance().getCommand(GetScriptEngineNamesCommand.class.getName());
        command.doExecute();
        Map<String, String> engineNames = command.getEngineNames();
        MessageSource messageSource = getMessageSource();
        Locale  locale = RequestUtils.getUserLocale((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext().getRequest(), Globals.LOCALE_KEY); 
        String label = messageSource.getFormattedMessage(locale, "com.soa.console.faces.script.select", new Object[] {});
        items.add(new SelectItem("", label));
        for (String name : engineNames.keySet()){
            items.add(new SelectItem(engineNames.get(name), name));
        }

    }catch (GException e){
        String eMessage = e.toString();
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("", eMessage);
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    return items;
}
```

Comment: The editor offers a button for "code sample". Or just begin the line with 4 spaces. That way the editor will not try to sanitize your text.

Comment: Share the code of the backing bean too...

Comment: Beannames start with a lowercase letter. Also consider to keep the GETer methods from all beans slim. Try to do all the processing in some initialize method, annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: I am not following. Did you mean I shud do the job of adding the items in the Constructor or something?

Comment: You need getter setters. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2036991/892994 and also read this tutorial for better understanding http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess getter method is not calling becuase you have bounded `<f:selectItems>` tag to the bean with **scriptEngines** but your getter method is **getScriptEngines()**.It should have been getscriptEngines().This could be the problem

Comment: May be you have some validation or conversion errors so bean values are not updating.You can use <h:messages> to show any messages

Comment: For a variable named as `scriptEngines`, the getter method will be `getScriptEngines()` only, hence there is no problem with the getter function name.

Comment: Some IDE will generate it as getscriptEngines().So i thought that would be the problem.