# use login class from another class

Tags: java, netbeans

I create login form and when press button, i want pass entered name to another class.

```
private void okButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    get_name = this.nameField.getText();
    get_pass = this.passwordField.getText();

}
```

In another class this prints null,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginFrame logframe = new LoginFrame();
    System.out.println(logframe.get_name);
}
```

Comment: chances are `get_name` is `null` when `main()` is excecuted

Answer (score 1):

The `main()` method gets called before `get_name` has a value set which is why you are getting `null`. If you debug the application (or just move the `print`) chances are `get_name` wont be `null` after `okButtonActionPerformed()` gets called.

Also its not a good practice to have public variables, you should set them to private and use [`getters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) and [`setters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) to access them instead. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) is a list of good reasons to do so.

Comment: It always print value before action perform. How can i get value after action performed?

Comment: move it some place where the value from the `textfield` has already been retrieved

Comment: I write 'public String getName(){return get_name;}' out of action performed and use this funtion in another class but it can't change

Comment: `getName()` is a method, you can't have a method inside a method in Java, I suggest you familiarize yourself with the [basics](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138747.html) before you continue further.

Comment: I try that but it prints frame0

Comment: if you move the statement as it is ofc its not going to work... change it to `System.out.println(this.get_name);` but honestly I insist there is a lot you need to learn there is no point on me getting your code to work if you don't understand what you are doing

Comment: i don't know much thing about gui, sorry. It didn't work also, I think it can't be done in java, so i'll change my algorithm.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the gui this is about the very basics and LOL ofc it can be done in Java, this and things 1million times more complicated its not that hard just grab a book or some online guide and give it a read there is loads of places you can learn for free the problem here is code needs to make sense in order to work

Answer (score 0):

The *action* listener takes it's action while running time, but static variables and methods will take their value(s) while compile time, so you can define your *textfield(s)* to some default values.

See this example:

```
private static int a ;
public static void test(){
 a = 3;
System.out.println(a);
a=5; 
System.out.println(a);
}
```

You probably guess the output will be (3 then 5), but actually it's not correct static variables will take the lase value, so the output will be

> 5
>   5

That's why they create dynamics as it's value(s)  will be change at run time like your `okButtonActionPerformed` gets the values of textfields after compiling(at run time), but while compiling it's set to `null` so the output will be

> null

You probably have a problem with accessing some classes field(s), see this example :

```
class Fruit{
 private String type;

 public String getType(){
       return this.type;
 }

 public void setType(String type){
       this.type = type;
}
}

public class Main{
//default constructor 
 public Main(){
 Fruitobj = new Fruit();
 obj.setType("Apple");
 System.out.println(obj.getType());
}
}
```

See also [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/tutorial-on-getters-and-setters)  also a good article answered by StackOverFlow.

Comment: How do i take changed text?

Comment: You can use `System.out.println` inside `actionPerfomed` method instead printing inside *main*  method.

Comment: But i want use it another class. Can i do that?

Comment: Yes you can, see I Edit my answer.