# Regarding access specifiers

Tags: java, object, access-modifiers

I defined a Class Base

```
class Base  
{  
    private int i;  
    Base(int i)  
    {  
        this.i = i;  
    }  
}
```

So object of Base class can access private variable.

```
class BaseDemo  
{  
        public static void main(String[] args)  
        {  
            Base objBase = new Base(10);  
            System.out.println(objBase.i);  
        }  
}
```

But it's giving me a compiler error I has private access in `Base`.

I'm confused while coding, what is wrong?

Comment: Anycode inside `Base` or its containing class can access `i`. You're trying to access `i` from `BaseDemo`.

Comment: i can not access variable i using object of its class. ok, similarly if a method is defined as private will not be accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
---------------------------------------------
public      Y      Y        Y           Y
protected   Y      Y        Y           N
no modifier Y      Y        N           N
private     Y      N        N           N
```

You should have a *getter* for that field. This is the whole idea of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). You should hide your implementation from outside and provide *setters* and *getters*.

Comment: Awesome ASCII table :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is easy. You have the variable "i" to private, you need a pojo (get y set) public to use the variable "i".

For example :

```
    public int getI() {
       return this.i;
    }
```

In the implementation use :

```
    objBase.getI();
```

PDT: Sorry for my english I speek Spanish

Answer (score 1):

`private` methods and variables have  access only with in the class. Not out side the class, even you create instance  you cannot access them.

From [`official docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

> The private modifier specifies that the member **can only be accessed in its own class**.

Answer (score 1):

BaseDemo is not an instance of `Base`, but even if it was a child of `Base` you've marked the field `i` as private. Only the class `Base` can access it, that's what `private` means. If it were `protected` then instances of `Base` or sub-classes of `Base` could access it.

Answer (score 1):

i is private property in class Base so you can't access directly.This one of object oriented programming concepts.

You can create getter for it

In base class

```
public int getI(){
    return this.i
}
```

In BaseDemo you can call it

```
 System.out.println(objBase.getI());
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to define a getter method to access your variable outside the class `BaseDemo`.

```
public int getI(){
   return i;
}
```

Maybe this will be useful for you:

- [How do getters and setters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/tutorial-on-getters-and-setters)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

the error is because your are voilanting the rules of access specifiers, private access specifier is used to make your variables accessable just with in the same calss