# How can I do this in Java? I can do it in Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

I'm trying to learn Java, I sort of know Javascript but I was wondering how I could do this in Java

I use this for Javascript.

```
var player = {
X: 32,
Y: 32,
Cloned: false;

};
```

I would use this to    drawImage(player.x, player.y) For example, how would I do something like this in java?

Comment: What do you want to do? What have you tried?

Comment: I'd recommend taking the time to learn Java, instead of relying on your JavaScript experience. The two languages are pretty different.

Comment: Java is not the same as JavaScript.

Comment: I know Javascript and Java aren't the same, but it Javascript I could create the player variable and create some other var's inside of it, and if I want to draw an image, I could use "player.x or player.y" as co ordinates? if you get me?

Comment: @user1231958 I think OP already knows that...

Answer (score 2):

In Java, which is [*statically typed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type-checking), there is *no* direct equivalent of the JavaScript ad-hoc object presented<sup>1</sup>.

Instead, one would create a [Player] [*class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) representing the "object" and then instantiate and use one or more instances. This class/instance approach, along with [subtyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping), is the *core* of the [Java OOP model](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3a_OOPBasics.html); there is no escape or viable alternative in Java - when using Java, write Java.

```
public class Player {
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    // and maybe `cloned`, etc.

    // maybe an "action"
    public void move(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // maybe a getter/setter
    // (although `move` above may obsolete the use of such setter)
    public int getX () { return x; }
    public void setX (int x) { this.x = x; }

    // and other relevant methods ..
};
```

And usage later might look like

```
// create new instance of class/type
Player player = new Player();
// manipulate and use
player.move(19, 81);
drawImage(player.getX(), player.getY());
```

While there is a "setter" provided in the Player class, only the "getter" was required for the usage; I prefer to use actions (e.g. `move`), and reducing mutable state *when* applicable, instead of allowing direct field manipulation as this can increase [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). In any case, see [How do getters and setters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work) wrt this tangent.

Also consider ["programming to interfaces"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface); for a real implementation I would likely have an Entity interface, implemented by the Player class, which understands positional movements and location. (While this is even more tangential, I wish that I had started programming "OOP" in this manner and I try to eschew type contracts based on implementing class or subtype relations!)

---

<sup>1</sup> This is true of Java, but it is not inherent of static typing; for instance, C# has [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) (albeit the static typing and inference is limited within the function) and different languages support strongly-typed records and/or structural typing and/or dynamic typing in an otherwise statically-typed language. Java, however, *requires* that such is codified into a class for support at the language level.

Comment: Getters/Setters are an anti-pattern. I wouldn't add them unless it's neccesary.

Comment: @user1231958 It depends on whom is asked and where such getters/setters are used.. I would agree that the Java approach is generally *ugly* compared to languages that "naturally" support such idioms; but in any case, if the state is to be modified directly (e.g. not through an direct action such as `move`), then I would much rather see the use of a setter than direct field access.

Comment: That's true, in any case you should never expose directly the properties and even getter/setter are better than public properties.

Comment: @user1231958 I usually trust the package-default, but I've just updated the post to explicitly make the fields protected to address that concern.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two different things here. Javascript is a client-side language for website scripting, and Java is a generic OO language that's useful for several projects and it works server-side.

Now you want to define this in Java. You do this using a class:

```
public class Player {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private boolean cloned;

    public Player (int x, int y, boolean cloned)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.cloned = cloned;
    }

    public void move (int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point getCoordinates()
    {
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

And then you instantiate as `new Player(32, 32, false);`.

This is a very rough example and can indeed be improved but it's basically like this.

Comment: I'm not sure it's safe to relegate javascript solely to a "client-side language for website scripting" anymore.

Comment: It has other uses indeed (MongoDB, etc), but its main use is as a scripting language for website clients.

Comment: And Java is for applets?

Comment: "MongoDB, etc" is a pretty strange way to characterize JavaScript's applications.

Comment: Applets, web system backends, standalone programs, whatever your needs are.

Comment: I'm not delving into the specific JS applications, just pointing out that it's true JS can be used for more than just websites. However JS is more used for websites.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in Java using HashMap i will give you an example, it might not be the same but the logic is in it.

```
HashMap player = new HashMap();
player.put("X", "32");
player.put("Y", "32");
player.put("Cloned", "false");

System.out.print( player.get("X") ); // will print 32
System.out.print( player.get("X") ); // will print 32
System.out.print( player.get("Cloned") ); // will print false
```