# Program runs, only getting nulls as return values

Tags: java, null

So this program runs fine, its a cycling manager for learning purposes. The problem is when I try to get a list of one rider's abilities: the return values are all null, even though they are set in one of my methods. What have I done wrong? Scroll down to public void abilities, the mistake seems to be located in this area. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CyclingManager2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //menyvalgene
    Menu m = new Menu();
    m.choice();

    }
}

class Menu {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Cyclist cy = new Cyclist();

//choices
public void choice() {

    int choice = -1;
    while (choice != 0) {

        System.out.println("Choose something: ");
        System.out.println("-0 will exit the program" + "\n-Pressing 1 will open the database menu");
        choice = in.nextInt();
        switch(choice) {
            case 0: choice = 0; break;
            case 1: cy.database(); break;
            default: System.out.println("You have to choose either 0 or 1"); break;
        }

    }
}
}

class Cyclist {

private String name;
private int mountain;
private int timeTrial;
private int sprint;
private int age;



public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setMountain(int mountain) {
    this.mountain = mountain;
}

public int getMountain() {
    return mountain;
}


public void setTimeTrial(int timeTrial) {
    this.timeTrial = timeTrial;
}

public int getTimeTrial() {
    return timeTrial;
}

public void setSprint(int sprint) {
    this.sprint = sprint;
}

public int getSprint() {
    return sprint;
}



public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}


public int getAge() {
    return age;
}




public void abilities() {

    //Pardilla blir til!
    Cyclist c1 = new Cyclist();

    c1.setName("Sergio Pardilla");
    c1.setMountain(75);
    c1.setTimeTrial(60);
    c1.setSprint(60);
    c1.setAge(30);

    System.out.println(getName() + "s abilities:");
    System.out.println("Mountain - " + getMountain());
    System.out.println("TimeTrial - " + getTimeTrial());
    System.out.println("Sprint - " + getSprint());
    System.out.println("Age - " +getAge());


    }

//databasemenu

public void database() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the database \nThese are the options:\n0 = Quit\n1: Abilities");
    int dbChoice = -1;

    while (dbChoice != 0) {

        System.out.println();
        dbChoice = in.nextInt();
        switch(dbChoice) {
            case 0: dbChoice = 0; break;
            case 1: abilities(); break;
            default: System.out.println("Choose either 0 or 1"); break;
        }

    } in.close();
}


public void riders() {


    System.out.println("Following riders are available in this database");
}



}
```

Comment: You should initialize your own object, not c1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
c1.getName()
```

instead

```
getName()
```

because objects are `null` by the default so you are getting values before `initialize` .that's why you are getting `null`

c1 hold a instance of `Cyclist class`. the  values you set only update to instance which hold by c1 method local variable

Answer (score 1):

You should use your `Cyclist` object to get their values ,

```
System.out.println(c1.getName() + "s abilities:");
System.out.println("Mountain - " + c1.getMountain());
```

You set the values to `Cyclist` object `c1` and not to the getters.

Read [How do getters and setters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work)