# What are getter and setter methods?

Tags: objective-c

I've heard about **getter** and **setter methods** in Objective C.

They are doing something else that's important, besides making it easier for you to set and get a variable.

What are they doing and how do they do it?

Comment: getters and setters are not just related to Objective C ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AccessorMethod.html and its various links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With setters you set the value of a property in a instance of a class. A getter is a function that gives you the variable as a return when you call it. You use setters and getters to control the access to private properties.

Comment: "A getter is a function that gives you the variable as a return when you call it."

Which variable do you refer to ?

Comment: @qonan Long ago we used to have to explicitly declare instance variables that the getters and setters use. Nowadays, that practice is discouraged as the compiler will synthesize these instance variables for us. So, up when you define a property called `name` the compiler will synthesize (a) a getter called `name`, (b) a setter called `setName`, and (c) an instance variable (which you generally won't use) called `_name`.