# Java: beginner help getting variable

Tags: java, methods

This is for a school project. I have built a simple class with 3 string variables and a constructor to fill these fields.

```
public class Names {
String firstName;
String middleName;
String lastName;

public Names(String name){
    System.out.println("Passed name is: " + name);
}

public void setFirstName(String name){
    firstName = name;
}
public void setMiddleName(String name){
    middleName = name;
}
public void setLastName(String name){
    lastName = name;
}

public static void main(String []args){
    Names drew = new Names("Drew");

    drew.setFirstName("Drew");
    drew.setMiddleName("Leland");
    drew.setLastName("Sommer");

    System.out.println(drew.firstName + " " + drew.middleName + " " + drew.lastName);
}

public getFirstName(String name){

}
public getMiddleName(String name){

}
public getLastName(String name){

}}
```

At the bottom where it is getFirstName, getMiddleName, getLastName I want to be able to pass something like getFirstName(drew) and have it return drew.firstName?

I am very new to java FYI.

Comment: Get the parameters out of your getXxxx() methods. They should be parameterless and should return the requested value. Any tutorial will show you this, in particular [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). Also look at [Java Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are ["getter" methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work) to return the values of instance fields. `drew` is your current `Names` instance here, therefore if you call these methods on this instance, you'll receive the values you've set with your "setter" methods. And since you're calling them on a specific instance, you don't need to pass it as a method argument. That is why these getter methods are normally parameterless.

They should look like this:

```
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
```

Please note that I've added the corresponding return type (`String`), because the data type of each instance field is `String`.

Your `println` call in the `main` method would then look like this:

```
System.out.println(drew.getFirstName() + " " + drew.getMiddleName() + " " + drew.getLastName());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}
```

This will return the firstName of the object you call it on.

You can call it like this:

```
System.out.println(drew.getFirstName() + " " + drew.middleName + " " + drew.lastName);
```

You can then do the same thing for getMiddleName and getLastName.

Comment: Should be `public String getFirstName()`

Answer (score 0):

Your get methods will be called by an instance of your Names class. When you create an instance of the class and assign it a variable name, just use that variable name to call the method and it will return the name for that instance.

```
//Instantiate the Names class
Names drew = new Names("Drew");

//Call methods to set the names
drew.setFirstName("Drew");
drew.setMiddleName("John");
drew.setLastName("Smith");

//Call methods to get the names
drew.getFirstName();   //Returns "Drew"
drew.getMiddleName();  //Returns "John"
drew.getLastName();    //Returns "Smith"
```

And, like others suggested, your get / set methods should be like this:

```
public void setFirstName(String n){
    firstName = n;
}
public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you said, "I want to be able to pass something like getFirstName(drew) and have it return drew.firstName"
so the impl is simple,

```
public String getFirstName(Names other) {
    return other.firstName;
}
```