# unrecognized symbol variable (JAVA)

Tags: java, polynomial-math

I have a class that finds the roots of a polynomial.  In the `Main` function, it is telling me that the variable `radicand` does not exist.  The function `rootradicand()` works fine, I have tested it with other values.

```
public double handleRadicand(double a, double b, double c){
    double radicand = b * b - (4 * a * c);
    return radicand;
}

public static void Main(String[] args){
    double a = 4;
    double b = 2;
    double c = 2;
    handleRadicand(a, b, c);
    rootRadicand(radicand);
    System.out.println(radicand);
}
```

Why is it telling me that `radicand` does not exist?

Comment: need to see the code. you should be able to paste it in. if its not formatting properly I am sure some can probably edit it for you.

Comment: Just paste your code in, and make sure each line has a minimum of four spaces of indentation. Please [edit] this question now.

Comment: Copy-paste the code.

Comment: if you don't know how you post code here, at least you will be expected to be able to search the solution via google as simple as this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your screenshot:

```
public double handleradicand(double a, double b, double c)
{
double rad = b*b - (4*a*c);
return rad;
}
```

At that time, you need to create a parameter as a container to get the return rad value.
For example:in your main method

```
double tem = handleradicand(a,b,c);
rootradicand(tem);
```

That should work.

Comment: I'm very new to Java, so do you think you could PM me and explain more in depth

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to use local variable of a method in other method, but which is out of scope for that variable. 
But since you are returning the value of handleradicand() method you can catch the value in a variable or you can directly call method as argument like this:

```
rootradicand(handleradicand(a,b,c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Radican cannot see the value from the method look like you need from getters and setters!
[How do getters and setters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work)

Comment: Could you give me an exmpale using my code please.  I read through it and i'm not sure i understand the this.

Answer (score 0):

radicand is defined in a different method (in handleradicand) and is therefore not visible in the method Main. 
In general variables defined in a method are not visible within another method

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot, `radicand` is unavailable in Main because it's not "Global" like you think it is, but is instead a local variable.  If you wanted `radicand` to be a global, it should be declared `public static` in a class somewhere (which is the closest thing to Global in Java), you'll need to refer to it as `NameOfClassRadicandIsIn.radicand`.

That said, Java is a language built specifically for a programming style that considers globals to be evil (and not without good reason, problems with globals are just awful things to debug).  Fortunately, your code doesn't even need that variable, because you can cut out the middle man with:

```
double radical = rootradicand(handleradicand(a,b,c));
```

Though if you do want to keep the variable, simply declaring it in your `Main` method would work:

```
double radicand = handleradicand(a,b,c));
double radical = rootradicand(radicand);
```

Note that I added `radical` because the line after your call to `rootradicand(...)` has the exact same problem.

As you learn the language if you do find yourself tempted to try using a global (i.e. `public static` in java, this should be considered a last resort.  You seem to be writing programs that only have one class now, but when you're dealing with multiple classes, any variables you want to expose between them should be declared as `private` and accessed with getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid:

```
return bover2a;
return radover2a;
```

and

```
return firstX;
return secondX;
```

You can't double return in a method in java, if you want this, you need to follow another approach like create a custom object and return the two values inside it.

And you are not assigning the returned value to any variable so every calculation made in `handleradicand(), rootradicand(), divideby2a(), findroots()` are lost once the call finished. You need something like:

```
double rad = handleradicand(a, b, c);
rad = rootradicand(rad);
...
```