# How to create get and set methods for parameters in a class?

Tags: java, get, set

I have a class I created.

```
public class mailCustomer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Name;
        int Id;
        String Address;
        Boolean IsPack;
    }
}
```

I need to creat get and set methods for my parametrs, Name, Id,Address, IsPack.
how do I do that, and where do I write them? after the "main" method? in the "main" method?

Comment: I would familiarize yourself more with the language. But how you would do it is you need to declare those variables outside the main what we call `globally` and then just for the heck of it put `private` in front of them. Then create the methods for them

Comment: try readin this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work

Comment: This is widely covered in tons of tutorials, even on [official Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Name;
    int Id;
    String Address;
    Boolean IsPack;

}
```

You can't create getters and setters for these, since they are not created in your class, but locally in your main method. What you want is:

```
public class MyClass{

String Name;
    int Id;
    String Address;
    Boolean IsPack;

// getter for Name
public String getName(){
  return this.Name;
}
// setter for Name
public void setName(String name){
  this.Name = name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}
}
```

For these you'll be able to create getters and setters.
It's (most likely) best to declare them private, though.
Also: following naming conventions could help other people easier read your code. Name (with capital N) is more suited as name of a class, while name (lowercase n) is the name of a variable.

Comment: Why the downvote, if I may ask?

Comment: I didn't down vote but i'm just saying you maybe want to show an example of a setter/getter method and how he would be able to do it. +1 from me otherwise

Comment: Good point, I've updated it with a getter and setter for Name (and a recommendation for following Naming conventions)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to declare the variables at the class level so that they can be used from anywhere within the class. Then after that you simply create a set and get method for each variable, like so

```
public class MailCustomer {
    String name;
    int id;
    String address;
    boolean isPack;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setIsPack(boolean isPack) {
        this.isPack = ispack;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public boolean getIsPack() {
        return isPack;
    }
}
```

It also appears that you have your naming conventions a little mixed up. In java, class names are capitalized, whereas variable and method names are camelCased

Comment: "class level" is better phrased compared to globally.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I edited my answer to reflect "class level"

Answer (score 1):

First, delete the main method from there. You are creating a class called mailCustomer that will create you `object` type of mailCustomer.

For this, you need three things: attributes (you have them there), a constructor and get/set methods. I will show you with a example, and you can guide from there. My class will be 'Rabbit' and it will have:

**Attributes**

-String eyes: Eye colour.

-String race: Where is it from.

**Constructor**

It will have one constructor, that will use both parameters.

**Methods**

It will have two getters and two setters, both for each attribute.

Here's my code for this class:

```
public class Rabbit{

   //Attributes

   private String eyes;
   private String race;

   //Constructor

   public Rabbit(String colour, String where){

   this.eyes = colour;
   this.race = where;
   }

   //Methods get/set

   public String getEyes(){

   return this.eyes;
   }

   public String getRace(){

   return this.race;
   }

   public void setEyes(String colour){

   this.eyes = colour;
   }

   public void setRace(String where){

   this.race = where;
   }

}
```

As you can see, you will use get methods to return an specific attribute from the class; and set methods will be used if you want to change one of the attributes from a created object (in my case, from a created 'Rabbit').

Later, if you want to make use of this class, you will create your Main class, into the same package where 'Rabbit' class is created.

```
package rabbit;

public static void main(String[] args){

Rabbit George = new Rabbit("brown","spanish");

}
```

Now try to do this with your class. I hope it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

As already said it seems that you are not familiar with Object Oriented Programming. It does not care. I just want to say that you can save a lot of time and improve your classes readability using lombok to automatically generate your getters and setters using annotations. You can find an example here : [LOMBOK](https://projectlombok.org/)