# How do I map multiple values in data table into a list?

Tags: cucumber-jvm

Here is my problem:

```
When I have step with data:
|Name | Description | data1 | data2|
| A   |  new A      |   abc  | xyz   |
```

The step definition

```
@When I_have_step_with_data(List<DataSet> dataSet){
    ////
}
```

I am trying to map the above data table into this domain object.

```
public class DataSet{
    private String name;  -> maps to Name
    private String description; -> maps to Description
    private List<Data> data;  -> creates list of Data with data1,abc and data2,xyz set.
}

public class Data {
    private string key;
    private String value;
}
```

Any pointers on how this can be achieved would be great.

Comment: In your step definition, you have `data1` (abc) and `data2` (xyz), but `Data` class have two attributes (key and value)... Which attribute corresponds to "abc" and "xyz"?

Comment: [key => data1 , value => abc]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say here is your scenario :

```
   When I have step with data:
    |Name | Description | data1  | data2 |
    | A   |  new A      |   abc  | xyz   |
```

You will create POJO class ([Getters and Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work))

You will create one class call "DataClass"

```
public class DataClass{
    private String Name;
    private String Description;
    private String Data1;
    private String Data2;


    public DataClass(String Name, String Description, String Data1,String Data2) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Description= Description;
        this.Data1= Data1;
        this.Data2= Data2;

    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }


    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }


    public String getData1() {
        return Data1;
    }


    public void setData1(String data1) {
        Data1 = data1;
    }


    public String getData2() {
        return Data2;
    }


    public void setData2(String data2) {
        Data2 = data2;
    }


}
```

## In Step Definition , Here is loop to get value

```
public class descriptionSteDefs{
    private Map<String, DataClass> DataClassList;

    @When("^When I have step with data$")
    public void description_data(List<DataClass> DataClassList) throws Throwable {
        DataClassList = new HashMap<String, DataClass>();

        for (DataClass DataClassValue: DataClassList) {
            String key = DataClass.getDescription;
            DataClassList .put(key, DataClassValue);
        }
    }
```