# Storing array from another class in java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I know that there's tons of ways to store an array from another class but what is the best approach that can be easily understood by everyone, even beginners?

Here is the sample code:

1st class:      // this is where to get the array to be stored

```
public class Example{
    private int[] Numbers = {3,2,1}//sample numbers        
}
```

2nd class: // this is where the array to be stored

```
public class Example2{
    public void Storage{
        int[] NumberStorage = /* this is where the Numbers from the
                                          1st class to be stored */
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't start variables and methods with capital letters or anything else but classes

Comment: NoobProgramer if an answer has solved your question please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Example` class create a [`getter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work):

```
public int[] getNumbers() { return Numbers; }
```

Then in your `Example2` class you can instantiate an instance of `Example` and call the `getter` like:

```
public void storage(){
    Example example = new Example();
    int[] NumberStorage = example.getNumbers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what You want

First Class
public class Class1{

```
private int [] Array = { 1,2,3,2,3,4};

public  Class1(){


   Class2 a =  new Class2();

   a.Class2(Array,6);
 }}
```

second class
public class Class2  {
   public void A( Array, size)
     //enter Sort here 
    }
}