# Java: how to parse a string in this situation?

Tags: java, string, class

So I have created a simple class in Java like this:

```
public class Book {
    private String author;
    private String title;

    public Book (String author, String title) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
    }
}

public void checkInfo
```

Is there a way to parse a string (property) in order to get Book properties like this, instead of doing `bookA.title` ?

```
Book bookA = new Book("George Orwell","Animal Farm")

String property = "title";
System.out.print(bookA.property);
```

Thanks in adance!

Comment: You could do something like `bookA.get(property);` (after you add a `get(String)` method in `Book`). I would prefer a `getTitle()` and `getAuthor()` (in which case you can access your fields with [JavaBean properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html)).

Comment: you need to implement `getter` and `setters` for Class `Book`. It will be more Convenient and better approach which introduced by java.

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't actually intend to have ``static`` in your class definition.  (Thinking you'd want multiple instances of ``Book``)

Comment: @chsbellboy right, will edit that

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments, the reason why i didnt implement getter methods is because,  it the real case im working with, there will be a lot more properties, intead of just author and title. So maybe getter is the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: Doesn't matter, add Getters for all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to access many properties as `String`, I suggest you using a `Map<String, String>` like this :

```
public class Book
{
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap();

    public void setProperty(String name, String value)
    {
        properties.set(name,string);
    }

    public String getProperty(String name)
    {
        return properties.get(name);
    }
}
```

Now you can use like this :

```
Book book = new Book();

book.setProperty("title","Animal Farm");
book.setProperty("author","George Orwell");

System.out.println("Book: " + book.getProperty("title") + " by " + book.getProperty("author"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created your `Book` as an object.
So, treat it like an object and add getters and setters.

In this case, that would be a method, `getTitle()` and a separate method `getAuthor()`.
For more information on getters and setters, see the responses to [this previous StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work)

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection:

```
 Field f = bookA.getClass().getDeclaredField("title");
 f.setAccessible(true);
 String title = (String) f.get(bookA);
 System.out.println(title);
```

Comment: I think he is searching for a much easier solution than that xd

Comment: @UDKOX yeah it seems so))

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code won't work because `title` is private. Second, I have no idea why you set `Book` class as static. Last, this (Java) is object oriented programming, so treat it like an object.

When you create a class you also add Getters & Setters to access the information inside. The code would look like this:

*Class*:

```
public class Book {
    private String author;
    private String title;

    public Book (String author, String title) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
    }
}

public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
}

public String getAuthor(){
    return this.author;
}
```

*Accessing the data*:

```
Book bookA = new Book("George Orwell","Animal Farm")

System.out.print("Book: " + bookA.getTitle() + " by " + bookA.getAuthor());
```

This would return :

```
Book: Animal Farm by George Orwell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see these few lines from your code:

```
private String author;  // both are private variables
private String title;
```

Here `author` and `title` both are `private` String . So you can't access these properties outside of the class.

So, you'll need to add public `getters` and `setters` that can be used to access the properties.

Answer (score 0):

you should change you Object class.. add getter and setter method..
here is example :

```
public class Book{ 
  String myauthor;
  String mytitle;
public Book (String author, String title){
  myauthor=author;
  mytitle=title;
}
public void setAuthor(String Autor){
myauthor=author;
}
public String getAuthor(){
return myauthor;
}
}
```

and create setter and getter for 'title' too..
if you want to get the title / author, just simply call

```
Book.getAuthor();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have getter/setter method for your class ;you can define access modifier as protected with static keyword.For example is:
under com.test package-There are two class.One is Book class and other is BookInSamePackage class.In Book class;if you define attribute title as protected static String title then in BookInSamePackage class ;You can access like that :'Book.title'.If you want to use this title attribute in class of another package;then this class need to extend Book class and can access like this way:Book.title in child class of another package.