# How do I use value from one class for another class Calling from main method

Tags: java

**One.java**

```
public class One {
    String asd;

    public class() {
        asd="2d6"
    }    

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Two a = new Two();
    }
}
```

**Two.java**

```
public class Two {
    ArrayList<String>data;
    String asd;

    public Two(String asd){
        this.asd=asd;
        data.add(this.asd);       
    }  
}
```

How do I use this asd value of second for third class calling from first class's main method.

```
**Third class**
```

Comment: By having getters and setters.

Comment: You can create a getter/setter in your `Two` class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do getters and setters work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work)

Answer (score 3):

Per comments of @Maroun Maroun and @Bennyz, you can create a getter and setter method in your Two class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Two {

    ArrayList<String> data;
    String asd;

    public Two(String asd) {
        this.asd = asd;
        data = new ArrayList<>(); //<-- You needed to initialize the arraylist.
        data.add(this.asd);
    }

    // Get value of 'asd',
    public String getAsd() {
        return asd;
    }

    // Set value of 'asd' to the argument given.
    public void setAsd(String asd) {
        this.asd = asd;
    }
}
```

A great site to learn about this while coding (so not only reading), is [CodeAcademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java).

To use it in a third class, you can do this:

```
public class Third {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Two two = new Two("test");

        String asd = two.getAsd(); //This hold now "test".
        System.out.println("Value of asd: " + asd);

        two.setAsd("something else"); //Set asd to "something else".
        System.out.println(two.getAsd()); //Hey, it changed!
    }

}
```

---

There are also some things not right about your code:

```
public class One {
    String asd;

   /**
   * The name 'class' cannot be used for a method name, it is a reserved
   * keyword.
   * Also, this method is missing a return value.
   * Last, you forgot a ";" after asd="2d6". */
    public class() {
        asd="2d6"
    }    

    /** This is better. Best would be to create a setter method for this, or
    * initialize 'asd' in your constructor. */
    public void initializeAsd(){
        asd = "2d6";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /**
         * You haven't made a constructor without arguments.
         * Either you make this in you Two class or use arguments in your call.
         */
        Two a = new Two();
    }
}
```

---

Per comment of @cricket_007, a better solution for the `public class()` method would be:

```
public class One {

    String asd;

    public One(){
        asd = "2d6";
    }
}
```

This way, when an `One` object is made (`One one = new One`), it has a `asd` field with "2d6" already.

Comment: I see the comment on the `public class()`, but perhaps you could fix it?

Comment: And `data.add(this.asd);` has a NullPointerException

Comment: @cricket_007 Delete `public class()` and use the `public void initializeAsd()` method. The NullPointerException occured 'cause the ArrayList data was not initalized, now it is.