# Accessing variable from other class

Tags: java

I have 2 classes that are not the main classes, but I want class B to access the variable from class A. I am not sure how to do it.

```
public class A (
    public int humanCakes;

    //This method is called by somewhere, when it is called it adds one
    public void humanCakes() {
        huamnCakes ++;
    }
 )

public class B {
    public void addUp() {
        Cakes = humanCakes + 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to define your variables. As written your code won't compile/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do getters and setters work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your variable in class A is public you can do the following

```
public class B{
    int Cakes;

    public void addUp(A obj)
    {
      Cakes = obj.humanCakes + 4;
    }
}
```

Note that you must past the A object into the addUp method in order to get the reference to the humanCakes variable