# Adding an element from main to an array in a class

Tags: java

I have a class names Packers with an array names Wins. I need to take an integer that I get from the main program and put it into the array. I have getters and setters I am just not sure how it works. Fairly new at java.

```
    //getters and setters
    public void setWins(int [] a){
        wins = a;
     }
    public int[] getWins(){
        return wins;
     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do getters and setters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work)

Comment: The above looks perfect — for setting and retrieving the `wins` array.  But I’m guessing that is not what you want to do.  A little more detail Is required.

Comment: in your code you have method to pass entire array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class packers{

public int [] wins = new int[5];

    public int[] getWins() {
        return wins;
    }

    public void setWins(int[] wins) {
        this.wins = wins;
    }

}       

public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
         Packers p = new Packers();
         // to pass single element to an existing array
         p.getWins()[index] = 2;

         // or you can create entire array and just pass it to setWins method.
          p.setWins(new int[]{2, 4, 6});
         }
}
```

in the first approach you are setting the value on the existing array.
In second approach you are pointing reference wins --> to the newly created array which you have passed.

just read basics about pass by value and reference.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the the object `new Packers()`, then call the getters and  setters:

```
Packers variableName = new Packers();
variableName.setWins(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(variableName.getWins()));
```