# How do I reference instances using an instance?

Tags: java, class, minecraft, instances

I'm trying to minimize how much I create an instance, as I am not particularly skilled in Java. Currently I have a set of instances of other classes in my Main, a quick example...

```
public final class ClassName extends JavaPlugin {

    AntiSwear antiSwear = new AntiSwear();
    Spam spam = new Spam();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }
}
```

And instead of making more and more instances, I just want to make an instance of the main class, `ClassName className = new ClassName();` and run something like `className.spam...`

Basically to put my gibberish into English: I just want to see how to reference instances using an instance.

Comment: `className.spam` should work

Comment: Does the `static` keyword cover what you need?

Comment: @PaulHicks the `static` one worked :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to go about this. The first way is to use the [**`public`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private) access modifier:

```
public AntiSwear antiSwear = new AntiSwear();
public Spam spam = new Spam();
```

This makes the instances accessible from an instance of `ClassName`, for example:

```
ClassName className = new ClassName();
className.spam...;
className.antiSwear...;
```

The second method involves [**getters** <s>and setters</s>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work), which provide a method that can be invoked by any class that contains an instance *and* has access, or by a subclass:

```
AntiSwear antiSwear = new AntiSwear();
Spam spam = new Spam();

public AntiSwear getAnitSwear(){
    return this.antiSwear;
}
public Spam getAnitSwear(){
    return this.spam;
}
```

Now you can invoke the getter accordingly:

```
ClassName className = new ClassName();
className.getSpam()...;
className.getAntiSwear()...;
```

The third method involves the [**`static`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class) access modifier:

```
public static AntiSwear antiSwear = new AntiSwear();
public static Spam spam = new Spam();
```

This makes the instances accessible from *every* external class, even those that do not contain an instance. This is because:

> `static` members belong to the class instead of a
>   specific instance.
>
> It means that **only one instance of a `static` field
>   exists** even if you create a million instances of the
>   class or you don't create any. It will be shared by all instances.

For example:

```
//Notice that I am not creating an instance, I am only using the class name
ClassName.spam...;
ClassName.antiSwear...;
```

Comment: Notably, for Minecraft mods, the only thing that really needs to be static is a reference to the main mod class instance itself. Forge does this pretty much *for* you (I don't know about Bukkit, etc), so you end up with, e.g.,  `ClassName.classNameInstance.spam` as the main mod class is essentially a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).