# JComboBox object use in JButton in java

Tags: java, netbeans, jbutton, jcombobox

[image] I want to use JComboBox object in JButton like if I select the desired text from JComboBox and click on button the image appear accorndingly, is it either possible or not, need help because I cant even make object of JCommbo in JButton. [image]

Comment: Your question is vague and a bit confusing.  Can you paste the actual code in a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (http://sscce.org/) on StackOverflow?

But yes, it's entirely possible to reference a JComboBox in the ActionListener for a JButton.

Comment: @RiaanNel I just edited the post, and in the second picture like if I click on desired time and click on Button the image of desired route open but I can't make object of JComboBox in Button if condition

Comment: @JohnSnow so if the user selects "6.A.M." in the combo box, then the button's text will change to "6.A.M."?

Comment: @CardinalSystem no the Button will open image of routes

Comment: @JohnSnow so what do you want the relation between the combo box and button to be?

Comment: The relation will be if the user clicks like "6.A.M" and clicks on JButton then an image of 6 A.M routes appear, I've tried your code but its not useful..
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
            if("6.A.M.".equals((String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem())) {
              SixAMRoute sam=new SixAMRoute();
              sam.setVisible(true);
              this.dispose();
    }
            else 
                System.out.print("Invalid");
        }~~ it always goes in else block @CardinalSystem

Comment: @JohnSnow I get it now. Where is your image file for 6 am routes, and where is the component that will contain it?

Comment: @CardinalSystem the image is in my E drive, I've also tried to give the link of image them I've made another Panel on which the image is stored and then Call the image class like this `             SixAMRoute sam=new SixAMRoute();
              sam.setVisible(true);
              this.dispose();` but that's not the problem, there's something wrong with my 'IF' condition

Comment: @JohnSnow I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make your [`JComomboBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) accessible from the [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) in order to get the selected text. You also need to use the proper method for getting the selected text, such as [`JComboBox#getSelectedItem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem()). Consider this example:

```
JComboBox<String> myComobBox = new JComboBox<String>();
JButton myButton =  new JButton("jButton");
myComboBox.addItem("6.A.M");
// Add button listener
myButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    // Use getSelectedItem instead of getText
    if(((String) myComboBox.getSelectedItem) == "6.A.M") {
         SixAMRoute sam = new SixAMRoute();
         sam.setVisible(true);
         this.dispose();
    }
});
```

If you want your  action listener to be it's own class, you will need to use [access modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47898382/5645656) to make the **JComboBox** accessible from the listener.