# How to access data in an object from an ArrayList?

Tags: java

For instance, I have a custom class called Boxcar, used like this:

```
public Boxcar(String c, int u, boolean r)
```

In another class, I initialize an ArrayList of Boxcars called train like this:

```
private ArrayList<Boxcar> train = new ArrayList<Boxcar>();
```

The problem I have is, I need to change String c to something else for every Boxcar in train. I imagine I need a for each loop so what I have now is:

```
public void setCargo(String replace)
{
    for(Boxcar b: train)
    {
        b = new Boxcar(replace);
    }
}
```

Which of course doesn't compile as it needs values for int u and boolean r. How can I access String c? Sorry for the noobish programming and I hope I was specific enough.

Comment: In your `Boxcar` class implement a setter for `String` c so you can manipulate it and change it's value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work

Comment: What's the implementation of the `BoxCar` ? Doesn't it have a getter/setter for `String c` ?

Comment: Can we have the full `Boxcar` code, plz?

Answer (score 1):

The code in your `for` loop doesn't change anything in the list. It is just assigning a new car to a the local variable `b` (provided it called the constructor correctly), leaving the array list unchanged.

What you want is changing a value on `Boxcar` objects, which you would typically do with a setter:

```
for(Boxcar b: train) {
    b.setC(replace);
}
```

This assumes that your `Boxcar` class has getters and setters:

```
public Boxcar(String c, int u, boolean r){
   //constructor code
}
public getC(){
    return this.c;
}
public setC(String c){
    this.c = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice is to have getters/setters in your class for variables that you wish to obtain or change once you have instantiated an object of that class.

So in your `Boxcar` class you would have something like

```
public int getU() {
    return u;
}

public void setU(int newValue){
    this.u = newValue;
}
```

This then enables you to keep the variable `u` private, whilst still enabling access via these getters and setters. 
You can then use your `for` loop to cycle through your `ArrayList` of `Boxcars` and call on the setter method for the value you wish to change and do so accordingly.

As a side note I'd suggest you change your variable names of `c`, `u` and `r` to something more human friendly as these give no indication as to what these values mean.