# How to set/call object and method in condition

Tags: java, object, constructor

How is it possible to set an object and method in a condition? I understand that, if the animal is over 50kg it weighs too much. But how about if an animal is *hangry*, *need Love* and *feel boring* return the method `feelingNegative()`?
I don't know how to set it. But after an animal sleeps, it is hangry. A thought would be:

```
Animal {
if (hangry == false && needLove == false && boring == false) {
  return feelingNegative();
}
}
```

still don't know how to set it.

```
public class Animal {

private boolean needLove;
private boolean hangry;
private boolean boring;
private int kg;

public boolean sleep() {
    return hangry = true;
}

public boolean watchTv() {
    return needLove = true;
}

public void feelingPositive() {
    System.out.println("I feel good");  
}

public void feelingNeutral() {
    System.out.println("Someting is missing...");
}

public void feelingNegative() {
    System.out.println("I need love, food and fun!");
}

public void weight(int kg) {
    if(50 < kg) {
        System.out.println("You ate way too much");
    }else {
        System.out.println("You need to eat more");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do getters and setters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work)

Answer (score 1):

The methods you are calling don't return anything (they are `void`). Just remove the `return`. And use boolean negation (`!`) instead of `== false`. Like,

```
if (!hangry && !needLove && !boring) {
    feelingNegative();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Method `feelingNegative()` doesn't return anything (`Void`). So you just have to define a method that call `feelingNegative()` when all the conditions are satisfied.

```
public void myMethod ()
{
    if(!hangry && !needLove && !boring)
         feelingNegative();
}
```