# What is Getter and Setter in Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

## What is getter and setter in android development.

And what is the use of **@Expose** in GSON.

```
@SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
```

Comment: same thing as in `java`. Please make sure you pass basic `java` training before you continue to Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do getters and setters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Getter** = accessing variable to be able to use

**Setter** = assigning a new value to variable

`@Expose` is used to decide whether a variable will be exposed for **serialization/deserialization** or not

Answer (score 0):

In Java, **getter** and **setter** are two conventional methods that are used for **retrieving** and **updating** value of a variable.

Something like:

```
public class Example {
    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

@Expose is an [annotation](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html). The official doc:

> An annotation that indicates this member should be exposed for JSON serialization or deserialization.