# use getter to pass value failed in java

Tags: java, getter

I am a beginner there are two classes that I want to use getter to pass the value of the field from another class. Therefore, I did something like this [How do getters and setters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work)

But it didn't pass the value. I got `IllegalArgumentException: bound must be greater than origin` from the `NimAIPlayer` since its bound and origin can't be the same value. What could be the reason?

Here is part of the `NimAIPlayer` class

```
public class NimAIPlayer extends NimPlayer implements Testable {

NimGame nimGame = new NimGame();
private int stoneTaken;


public int moveStone() {
    int balance = nimGame.getStoneBalance();
    int initialStone = nimGame.getInitialStone();
    int upperBound = nimGame.getUpperBound();
    if (initialStone == balance) {
        stoneTaken = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, upperBound + 1);
        return stoneTaken;

    } else if (balance < upperBound){
        stoneTaken = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,  + balance + 1);
        return stoneTaken;

    } else if (balance >= upperBound){
        stoneTaken = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, upperBound + 1);
        return stoneTaken;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And here is part of my `NimGame` class

```
public class NimGame extends Nimsys {

NimPlayer player1;
NimPlayer player2;

int stars;
int stoneBalance;
int initialStone;
int upperBound;
int takeStone;

public NimGame() {

}

public NimGame(NimModel nimModel, int initialStone, int upperBound , NimPlayer player1, NimPlayer player2) {
    this.initialStone = initialStone;
    this.upperBound = upperBound;
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.player2 = player2;
}

public int getInitialStone() {
    return initialStone;
}

public int getUpperBound() {
    return upperBound;
}

public int getStoneBalance() {
    return stoneBalance;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly it has failed and for which field?

Comment: can u put full stacktrace

Comment: I  called the getter in the `NimGame` to do the computation. In the `moveStone()` method. I print out all the value I get, it's all zeros. @AnishekRamanBharti

Comment: @Ambika I have six classes to go through all the stacktrace... It would too huge.

Comment: All fields are zero beacuse you have not initialized the fields which you are trying to get in moveStone()

Comment: okay, is there a proper way to handle this or any articulate articles? thank you @AnishekRamanBharti

Comment: The values will be passed in when I call the entire `NimGame` to be played. How can I use the getter to get the values?

Comment: You can use either parameterized constructor or setter to set the values of NimGame . Once values are set , getters method can be used to get the values easily .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parameterized constructor in NimGame class

**NimGame.java**

```
public NimGame(NimModel nimModel, int initialStone, int upperBound , NimPlayer player1, NimPlayer player2 , int stoneBalance) {
            this.initialStone = initialStone;
            this.upperBound = upperBound;
            this.player1 = player1;
            this.player2 = player2;
            this.stoneBalance = stoneBalance;

        }
```

**NimAIPlayer.java**

You can initialize NimGame object like this using parameterized constructor

```
NimGame nimGame = new NimGame(new NimModel(),10,15,new NimPlayer(),new NimPlayer(),8);
```

Using **NimGame nimGame = new NimGame()** will initialize all fields with default values like null for object type and 0 for int type . This will result **getting 0 for all interger fields when you print inside moveStone method** .

Comment: Thank you, sir! I got the point. But, I've already used this instantiation to play the game. I mean, the values of the first two parameters have been set and been passed to the `NimGame` class. How can I extract the values that already instantiated?

Comment: getter method can provide that value easily .

Comment: NimGame nimGame = new NimGame(new NimModel(),10,15,new NimPlayer(),new NimPlayer(),8);    int initialStone = nimGame.getInitialStone();   this will give 10 .

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiated the nimGame class you used the default constructor which has not instantiated the values.
That would make the values null.
Instantiate the values in the nimGame class first.

```
public class NimGame extends Nimsys {

NimPlayer player1;
NimPlayer player2;

int stars;
int stoneBalance;
int initialStone;
int upperBound;
int takeStone;

public NimGame() {
stars = default_value;
stoneBalance = default_value;
initialStone = default_value;
upperBound = default_value;
takeStone = default_value;
}

public NimGame(NimModel nimModel, int initialStone, int upperBound , NimPlayer player1, NimPlayer player2) {
    this.initialStone = initialStone;
    this.upperBound = upperBound;
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.player2 = player2;
}

public int getInitialStone() {
    return initialStone;
}

public int getUpperBound() {
    return upperBound;
}

public int getStoneBalance() {
    return stoneBalance;
}
```

Comment: What if the values have already been passed in? Like I already set the `initialStone` and the `upperBound` from other class.

Comment: were the values passed like this?NimGame nimGame = new NimGame(nimModel, initialStone, upperBound , player1, player2);

Comment: In which class do you instantiate the args?

Comment: In the class called `Nimsys`. It's the main control panel there. I use it when I want to start a game.