# How does the SetObject method work for a class

Tags: java

[This is the picture for question which i am asking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl1la.png)
[Please look at this picture also to understand the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou2F2.png)

In the image which I have mentioned here. It shows the setObject method inside the Class A. (There are 2 classes 1 called class A and another Class B). Inside class a it has created a method called set B Object. I need someone to explain me what this code does. The teacher which teaches is very bad, he cant even speak english properly. Please if anyone can explain it to me. That would be a big help

I know how to write a normal Set method, but I am not sure of a SetMethod for a class.

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work

Comment: `this.BObject` stores a reference to the `classB` instance - and please don't learn those naming conventions, Java classes should start uppercase (`ClassB`), variable names start lowercase (`bObject`), it's incredibly confusing if you turn it around 180°

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about this method.

Class A has a member of type Class B called `BObject` (BTW - this name doesn't follow Java's naming conventions). The `setBObject` methods gets an instance of `classB` and saves it to the data member in the `classA` instance, exactly the same as any other setter would do.